# How to typeset subscript in usual text mode?

Tags: subscripts

It's easy to make subscripts in math mode: `$a_i$`.

How do I make a subscript outside math environment, like<sub>this</sub>?

Comment: Related: [Superscript outside math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47324/5764)

Answer (score 210):

Note that `\textsubscript` enters math mode as well. This might produce problems in PDF strings where math is not allowed, for instance in bookmarks. If you used hyperref and simply used `\textsubscript` in a section heading, hyperref would complain about the math shift. The command `\texorpdfstring` comes to the rescue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{like\textsubscript{this}}{like this}}
\end{document}
```

That applies to math and math symbols in sectioning headings of course as well.

*Since 2015, LaTeX provides the fixltx2e features by default, so you can omit `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`then.*

Comment: Useful to know!  NB: just to be clear, the `\texorpdfstring` command is in the hyperref package.  Would any other package have problems with this?

Comment: pdftex could have problems. Try `\pdfoutline goto page 1 {/Fit} count 0 {like\textsubscript{this}}` and have a look at the bookmark.

Comment: this is a neat trick ! I've had problems with math in section headers before.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for what is the preferred choice for setting subscript in LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz  you might add some short recommendation about loading the package `fixltx2e` as one of the first packages. It has some incompatibilities (See [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204410/package-fixltx2e-conflicts-with-float-and-cannot-be-resolved-in-lyx)) that can be solved in this way. I have been almost 1 hour debugging such a problem ( yes, my code was long, but even ).

Comment: As Fran points out below, it appears that \usepackage{fixltx2e} is no longer needed.

Comment: @Isaac thanks, I added a note to the answer to make this well visible.

Comment: Maybe add some brief explanation (in the code write `\texorpdfstring{ <actual text to be typesetted, contain \textsubscript> }{ <plaintext to be put to table of contents, does not contain \textsubscript> }`)? Or maybe link to [beamer - Hyperref warning - Token not allowed in a PDF string - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string) for explanation

Answer (score 125):

This is included in the [fixltx2e](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}
like\textsubscript{this}
\end{document}
```

Interestingly (?), there's a `\textsuperscript` command already in LaTeX.

This is included already in the [KOMA-Script](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=koma-script) bundle.  If you want to typeset chemical formulas, have a look at the [mchem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/) package.

(Thanks to Caramdir for those last two.)

Comment: In @StefanKottwitz 's answer, he has used the same `fixltx2e` package. But he's also used the `hyperref` package. Is there a redundancy somewhere or am I missing something?

Comment: @ShashankSawant Stefan's answer is: "**if** you use `hyperref` then you might want to do it like ..."  So if you are already using hyperref and you want the subscript in headers, use his solution.  Otherwise, this one ought to work.

Comment: As Fran points out below, it appears that \usepackage{fixltx2e} is no longer needed.

Comment: `fixltx2e` is indeed no longer needed. See the [CTAN page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e): "This pack­age does noth­ing other than is­sue a warn­ing in cur­rent LaTeX Re­leases."

Answer (score 91):

**Actual solution in LaTeX**

Just write `like\textsubscript{this}`

You do not need preamble fixes anymore. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    like\textsubscript{this}
\end{document}
```

Because all the fixes of package `fixltx2e` [were enabled by default in the LaTeX format in 2015](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews22.pdf), the odd lack of this "expectable" command in LaTeX kernel is now history.

**Old story**

Just for the record: Before of the already cited `fixltx2e`  package (**now obsolete**), the command `\textsubscript` was also supplied by exactly the same macro by  the little package `subscript` (**no longer in TeX Live**):

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsubscript[1]{\@textsubscript{\selectfont#1}}
\newcommand{\@textsubscript}[1]{{\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
```

But this command is still accessible in the `changes` packages that is  <strike>actually the best option</strike> since is still in both MiKTeX and TeXLive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes} % Not needed since 2015 
\begin{document}
like\textsubscript{this}
\end{document}
```

Another option could be a simpler user macro without `\makeatletter` stuff. To set the  subscript size, the `relsize` package could help:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\def\textsubscript#1{\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\textscale{.6}{#1}}}}}
\begin{document}
\huge         a\textsubscript{th} A\textsubscript{th}\par
\Large        a\textsubscript{th} A\textsubscript{th}\par
\normalsize   a\textsubscript{th} A\textsubscript{th}\par
\small        a\textsubscript{th} A\textsubscript{th}\par
\footnotesize a\textsubscript{th} A\textsubscript{th}\par
\tiny         a\textsubscript{th} A\textsubscript{th}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as [Andrew's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1014/5764).

Comment: @Werner I don't think so. Andrew's answer is about the `fixltx2e`, I mention the older package `subscript`. I have not seen any mention to this package in any other answer. (and yes, I know that the command is  exactly the same in both packages, I said "just for the record" for this reason...).

Comment: This has to be the approved answer!

Answer (score 47):

If you don't want to install additional packages you can use the following syntax:
like `$_{\text{this}}$`.

This will only require the use of one of the ams packages, for example `amsmath`, which is standard for most latex installations.

Alternatively, you can define a command `\textunderscript` in the beginning of your document:

```
\newcommand{\textunderscript}[1]{$_{\text{#1}}$}
```

Comment: `\text` needs the `amstext` package: perhaps you are thinking of `\textup`?

Comment: Yes, for \text you need one of ams packages (amsmath is enough), but I don't carry about that because I use amsmath in virtually all my latex documents.

Comment: Or you could use \mathrm{}, or even nothing... It's so tiny no-one will notice... =P

Comment: How do you use the command you defined? I tried `a_1` and it results in an error.

Comment: Amir, with the command from my answer you can write `a\textunderscript{1}`. But, please, take a look at the Fran's answer.

Answer (score 19):

Since I've always been bugged by the fact that LaTeX's sscripts need math mode (setting normal text inside math mode have issues with LuaTeX's directionality), motivated by this question, I "stole" the subscript/superscript code from ConTeXt which is set entirely in text mode, with quick hacks to get it work with plain TeX (needs pdftex/luatex though), it is [here](http://gist.github.com/563837) for now, if there is interest may be it can be turned into some package.

Comment: As a bonus, it also provides a command, `\lohi`, to set sub and superscripts simultaneously.

Comment: Neat. I vote for a package.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Can I ask whether this was ever made into a package?

Comment: @solisoc No it didn’t.

Answer (score 19):

LaTeX provides `\raisebox{<len>}{<stuff>}` (based on TeX's `\raise`) which raises (and boxes) `<stuff>` by `<len>`. A negative `<len>` drops the contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
It's easy to make subscripts in math mode: $a_i$.

How do I make a subscript outside math environment, 
like\raisebox{-.4ex}{\scriptsize this}?
\end{document}​
```

Comment: It seems like this nice trick does not work inside captions and tikz, am I wrong?

Comment: @mmj: Since it forms part of a moving argument, you have to use `\protect\raisebox{..}{...}`.

Comment: How do you know how much length to lower it?

Comment: @Mario S. E.: through trial and error I have come to -1/3 ex.

Answer (score 15):

In ConTeXt, you can write

```
like\low{this}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here, I provide the subscript equivalent of this answer, [Superscript outside math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode/140703#140703).  I show how the subscript depth may be set, as well as the subscript size, using my `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\textsub[1]{\stackengine{-.5ex}{}{\scriptsize#1}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
a\textsubscript{th}A\textsubscript{th}\\
a\textsub{th}A\textsub{th}\\
\renewcommand\textsub[1]{\stackengine{-.4ex}{}{\footnotesize#1}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
a\textsub{th}A\textsub{th}\\
\renewcommand\textsub[1]{\stackengine{-.5ex}{}{\tiny#1}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
a\textsub{th}A\textsub{th}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In answer of community wiki (Fran) is stated that the package `'fixltx2e`` is obsolete. Why you still use it? Does ``stackengine`` work without it?

Comment: @Zarko I need it only to show `\textsubscript` for comparison in row 1.  The `stackengine` package does not need it.

Comment: B. Steglets, thank you for information. I found ``stackengine`` interesting for many my needs, but I still learning how to use it. Implementation of ``\textsubscript`` and ``\textsupercsript`` and combination of both are my first ongoing experimetns with it.

Comment: @Zarko Best wishes!

Answer (score 5):

The way I do it is by using mathrm inside math environment:

```
$\mathrm{like_{this}}$
```

Comment: This and `\text` from `amsmath` are the simplest solutions.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `$\text{}$` version and you have selected a different font (other than roman serif) then `$\textnormal{}$` matches the font of the document. If you are using the default fonts, `\text{}` will work great.

Answer (score 3):

I get this done by using the `mhchem` package. It's normally used for writing chemical formulas, but you can use it for this problem, too.

```
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{like_{this}}
\end{document}
```

`mhchem` doesn't print spaces when you put them in the subscript part. To get the spaces in the subscript part, you'll have to escape them using backslashes:

```
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{like_{this\ and\ this\ and\ this}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -8):

I am new to LaTeX but I have learnt reading the error messages they help a lot with the solution itself. That is where I found that without `$` before and after your subscript function LaTeX would give your errors after quick build.

```
Like$_{this}$
```

Use `$` to start and end the section of your command without these the math commands of subscript and superscript won't work. You don't need any additional packages for using these commands.

`_{•}` for subscript
`^{•}` for superscript

Comment: Welcome, there is a clear distinction between math mode and text mode, on a functional level and concerning fonts. You answer is very bad advice and will lead to confusion among new users.