# Hyperref warning - Token not allowed in a PDF string

Tags: beamer, hyperref, pdftex

When compiling a beamer presentation and using the following `\author` command

```
\author{Name \\ \texttt{my.email@domain.com}}
```

I get the following hyperref warning in my logfile

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\\' on input line 15.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\new@ifnextchar' on input line 15.
```

I understand that this has to do with hyperref setting the PDF metadata, where the linebreak does’t make much sense and should be removed.

Trying to set

```
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Name}}
```

does’t change the situation, seems like hyperref is still looking at the author command.

How do I get the desired display of author name with email and still keep hyperref happy?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

There's the aptly, if verbosely, named macro `\texorpdfstring`, which takes two arguments and uses the first for (La)TeX and the second for pdf, so something like

```
\author{A.U. Thor\texorpdfstring{\\ foo@bar.baz}{}}
```

should work.

The command is not defined in the document preamble, so `\author{}` must be specified after `\begin{document}` in this case.

(Yes, I've avoided the issue that I don't know off the top of my head if `\url` is allowed to go inside another argument...)

Comment: It's nice. There ought to exist an option in hyperref to automatically replace all non-allowed tokens by {} for the pdf string. Doing this for all my section titles is a hassle.

Comment: I used it in `\author`, before `\begin{document}`, and it worked. I also used a shorter syntax - `\texorpdfstring{\\}`

Answer (score 101):

While Ulrich's answer is correct and works, there is a more general and transparent way to work around the issue.

The `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` command from the `hyperref` package can be used to redefine commands that are usually not supported in PDF bookmark strings.

In the OP example, the offending commands are `\\` and `\texttt`, which can be redefined to do something else in this way:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\\{}%
  \def\texttt#1{<#1>}%
}
```

Then, the author can be specified in the document without any special care:

```
\author{Name \\ \texttt{my.email@domain.com}}
```

and will be formatted as is, but then put as `Name <my.email@domain.com>` in the PDF info strings.

Comment: Best answer. For me, the offender was glossaries. I had to do `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
 \def\Glsxtrshort{}%
 \def\glsxtrshort{}}`

Comment: What would be the syntax for the "math" command, e.g. `\section{Local $d$-Privacy}`?

Comment: In this case you can use the LaTeX way of inline math, i.e. `\(d\)`. Then you can redefine `\(` and `\)` inside the command to expand to nothing

Answer (score 44):

One can also add

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{naturalnames}{hyperref}
```

before `\documentclass{beamer}` to remove many messages generated due to national (non-English) section titles, like

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\PD1\cyrn' on input line 33.
```

P.S. Usually one may get up to few thousands of those even for a simple presentation, and parsing of them takes few extra seconds for many IDEs even on a modern box.