# Line break in section name

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

Is there any easy way to force a line break in a section name manually, without getting the line break in the Table of Contents? It's because I have a rather long section name, and it breaks just only the last three letters and it looks stupid, but there is no problem in ToC. I have tried double-\ but it breaks the line in the ToC as well.

I have looked at [How to put a line-break in section heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14008/how-to-put-a-line-break-in-section-heading) and tried

```
\texorpdfstring
```

And it does break the line, but the new line starts below the section number, not below the section name.

(I'm using PDFLaTeX for compiling in TexMaker, and I would prefer not to change that.)

Another solution could be to squeeze the title a bit, if that is possible? I don't think it would be noticeable.

Comment: try putting the broken word in an `\mbox`.  and/or try using a tie `~` to attach a couple of words that you want to keep together.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked mentions using the optional argument; I've rephrased the answer so that it becomes more explicit.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't get that by then I think. I see now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the optional argument for the section (inside `[...]`) which will used for running content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[my section]{This is going to \\ go for two lines}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Make sure to use a short title in the optional argument.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I actually just used the same title in the optional argument, as there is no problem in ToC (it's only 3 letters too much for one line in the text).