# page number misaligned in toc

Tags: table-of-contents

One of the headings of my paragraph is so long that it is pushing the page number in toc to the right side. it looks misaligned from rest of numbering.

Yes, I am using paragraph as heading for giving numbering to it.

So the heading is like

\paragraph{some thing in the header (11235)}
detailed text here .....

how do I give a break point between header and (11235) so that in ToC (11235) spills over to next line.

My ToC currently looks like as in attached picture.[image]

I have attached a picture for better view.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is necessary.

Comment: A MWE is really the only way to speak very specifically about your situation.

Comment: I tried pasting my tex code but it all got misaligned when I paste here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there is a very small window in terms of line length that will push the page number out of alignment.  The text should wrap if a longer section title is provided.

That said, if you must, you can add a line break to the text that appears in the TOC by using the optional parameter to the section command:

```
\paragraph[some thing in the header\\(11235)]{some thing in the header (11235)}
```

More detail on how this works is given at [How to put a line-break in section heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14008/how-to-put-a-line-break-in-section-heading).  Here, however, the line break was desired in the body of the report without affecting either the TOC or the text in the PDF bookmark.