# Email field in beamer class?

Tags: beamer

I am new to the beamer class and I am struggling to include my email info in a presentation.

I tried `\email` but there is no such field. I tried the below but the theme over-rode the `\small` making the email appear too big.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,english]{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme[named=black]{structure}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\title{Some Great Long Title}
\author{Author\\{\small email@email.com}}
\institute{ABC}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way of inserting a row of text between author and institute with no formating?

Comment: You can just leave out the `\small` altogether to get it in the same size as the title. Alternatively you can replace it with `\tiny` to get something smaller than the title. If this is too small, you can use `\scriptsize` or `\footnotesize`.

Comment: In the sidebar, the email comes out _bigger_ than the author. That's weird…

Comment: However, I seem to get Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\\'  error when I tried to use new line in author field

Comment: \tiny also yeilds warning:     LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/n' in size <4> not available(Font)              size <5> substituted ........  But I guess it's alright since the output looks fine

Comment: For others' interest,   http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string  gets rid of the first warning. For the second warning, the redefinition of tiny seems to do the trick:  http://texblog.net/latex-archive/presentations/beamer-warnings/

Answer (score 16):

use

```
\author{\texorpdfstring{Author\newline\url{email@email.com}}{Author}}
```

Comment: I usually use `\href{mailto:some@email.com}{some@email.com}`.

Comment: nice, but I didn't ... ;-)

Comment: That gives me 36 warnings and no change in fontsize.

Comment: use `\texorpdfstring` if you want get rid of it

Comment: You might want to add some more information on that, even though I understand how to use it, the OP might not.

Comment: Will this mess up the metadata?

Answer (score 8):

Personally I don't like the email address to be displayed right below the name. I'm usually setting it up in the bottom left corner. I'm using the `filll` glue to allow adding text below the `\maketitle` on the same page without changing the positioning of `\maketitle` outputs.
Firstly I define `\vfilll` in analogy to `\vfil` and `\vfill`.

`\def\vfilll{\vskip 0pt plus 1filll minus 0pt }`

Now I can manipulate the layout of the titlepage with ease:

```
\begin{frame}
  \vfilll
  \titlepage
  \vfilll
  \usebeamerfont{institute} Contact: \url{email@email.com}
\end{frame}
```

Here's complete example document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\vfilll{\vskip 0pt plus 1filll minus 0pt }

\author{John Doe}
\title{My cool title}
\institute{Institute of Institutes}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \vfilll
  \titlepage
  \vfilll
  \usebeamerfont{institute} Contact: \url{email@email.com}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It renders the following:

[image: Rendering of above code]

I'm using `institute` font size, because that's not annoyingly huge. Feel free to play with that value or use an explicit font size like `\footnotesize` if you prefer. Also this works nicely with different templates (even those with footlines) and also when a logo is included.