# How to display e-mail addresses for multiple authors in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, formatting

I have a Beamer presentation with multiple authors and I would like their e-mail addresses to be displayed underneath each author name. The post [Email field in beamer class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41246/2675) is simple enough to do for a single author, but for multiple authors the results are disappointing:

```
John Doe
john@example.com Jane Doe
jane.doe@example.com
```

instead of

```
    John Doe          Jane Doe
john@example.com  jane@example.com
```

I can sort-of understand why this is happening, but I am not sure how to resolve this. In a `tabular` environment fixing this would involve a number of paragraph boxes or minipages...

Is there an easy way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution with three parts:

1. optional argument of `\author` is authors for `infolines`
2. first argument of `\texorpdfstring` is authors for title page (two columns with name and email)
3. second argument of `\texorpdfstring` is authors for PDF information.

The source:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\title{Title}
\author[J.\,Doe \& J.\,Doe]
{%
  \texorpdfstring{
    \begin{columns}%[onlytextwidth]
      \column{.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      John Doe\\
      \href{mailto:john@example.com}{john@example.com}
      \column{.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      Jane Doe\\
      \href{mailto:jane.doe@example.com}{jane.doe@example.com}
    \end{columns}
  }
  {John Doe \& Jane Doe}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I finally resorted to using a plain-old `\parbox`:

```
\newcommand{\newauthor}[2]{
  \parbox{0.26\textwidth}{
    \texorpdfstring
      {
        \centering
        #1 \\
        {\scriptsize{\urlstyle{same}\url{#2}\urlstyle{tt}}}
      }
      {#1}
  }
}

...

\author{
  \newauthor{John Doe}{john@example.com}
\and
  \newauthor{Jane Doe}{jane@example.com}
}
```

Using a smaller, non-monospace font for the e-mail addresses helps keep their width down, but it is not critical. The width of the `\parbox` should probably be adjusted, depending on the number of authors and the length of their names and mail addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible approach that redefines the `titlepage` template in order to insert two authors.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%-------------------------------------------------
% title page with two authors
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true,sep=8pt,center]{title}
\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\begin{beamercolorbox}{author}
\begin{columns}[T]
\column{.28\textwidth}%
\centering
\usebeamerfont{author}John Doe\\
john@example.com
\column{.25\textwidth}%
\centering
\usebeamerfont{author}Jane Doe\\
jane@example.com
\end{columns}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute \par
\vfill
\centering
\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
\vfill
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center]{titlegraphic}
\inserttitlegraphic
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\title{My title}
\subtitle{my subtitle}
\institute{My institute}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Authors are inserted by means of the `columns` environment and the result is:

[image]

Of course this holds regardless the `theme` chosen and it is possible to extend it: three authors, three columns and so on.

Comment: Uh, not to sound ungrateful, but I was hoping for something a little bit simpler :-)