# Email contact in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am using `\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}`.

I put

```
\title{}
\author{sam \& jony}
\institute{}
```

Then I want to put email address of authors, how to do so?

Comment: Related (perhaps duplicate): [How to display e-mail addresses for multiple authors in Beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63259/13304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{This is my title}
\author[sam \& joey]
       {\parbox[t]{1.5in}{sam \\\texttt{sam@somewhere.edu}} \and 
        \parbox[t]{1.5in}{joey \\  \and \texttt{joey@somewhere.edu}}}
\institute{Somewhere U.}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
next
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Forgot about that.  Thank you.