# How to make new command, but avoid using \newcommand in preamble

Tags: beamer, macros

I am making a latex template for presentation slides using `beamer` class.

I want to allow people to enter their `email address` and `employee_id` in the main `tex` file, before the line of `\begin{document}`.

I know the following codes, but it shows `\newcommand` in the preamble. I think it is not a clean template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Latex Template for Presentation Slides}
\date{7 February 2018}
\author{My Name}
\newcommand{\email}{my.name@email.com}
\newcommand{\employeeid}{ID: 123456}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \insertauthor
    \email
    \employeeid
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want the following way. And the definition of `\newcommand{\email}{}` and `\newcommand{\employeeid}` should be added in `beamerinnerthememytheme.sty` file, and the users should only give their info in the main `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Latex Template for Presentation Slides}
\date{7 February 2018}
\author{My Name}
\email{my.name@email.com}
\employeeid{12345678}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \insertauthor
    \email
    \employeeid
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have seen post [Email field in beamer class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41246/email-field-in-beamer-class), but it is not what I want. I want:

1. more than email address (e.g. employee id)
2. email address, employee id can be shown in different location/slides than the author name.

Do you know how to define such commands `\email` and `\employeeid`?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a wrapper macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define some wrapper macros that store the email and the employeeid to some place. If it is internal, use some `@` in the macro names and place them without `\makeatletter...\makeatother` in the `.sty` file.

```
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\gdef\email@internal{#1}}
```

defines `\email@internal` to be the content of `#1` -- this is the way how it is done with `\@title` and `\@author` in LaTeX's core.

I suggest to use `\insertemail` and `\insertemployeeid` as names similar to `\insertauthor`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Latex Template for Presentation Slides}
\date{7 February 2018}
\author{My Name}

\makeatletter
%First empty definitions
\def\email@internal{}
\def\employeeid@internal{}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\gdef\email@internal{#1}}
\newcommand{\employeeid}[1]{\gdef\employeeid@internal{#1}}
\newcommand{\insertemail}{\email@internal}
\newcommand{\insertemployeeid}{\employeeid@internal}
\makeatother 

\email{gandalf@mordor}
\employeeid{ID: 123456}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \insertauthor

    \insertemail

    \insertemployeeid
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The standard would be something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\gdef\@email{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Then the macro `\@email` keeps the value one gives to `\email`