# Hyperref - Token not allowed

Tags: hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperref warning - Token not allowed in a PDF string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string)

The following code:

```
\subsection{The classes $\mathcal{L}(\gamma)$}
```

generates the errors:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 1938.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\gamma' on input line 1938.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 1938.
```

What do I have to do to keep `\gamma` in the subsection, so that it is also listed in the table of contents?

Answer (score 428, accepted):

The PDF bookmarks are a different thing than the table of contents. The bookmarks are not typeset by TeX: they simply are strings of characters, so no math or general formatting instructions are allowed.

The easiest method to avoid the warnings is to use `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\subsection{The classes \texorpdfstring{$\mathcal{L}(\gamma)$}{Lg}}
```

where in the second argument you put the best approximation possible; after all the bookmarks are only a guide for consulting the document.

Comment: Ahh, I see, those are PDF bookmarks, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answering this, even though the question was a duplicate: I couldn't tell if maths mode in section titles would work the same as in the other answers to this problem.

Comment: In which package is texorpdfstring defined?

Comment: @EduardoSanchez: there is no package to import.

Comment: so, @egreg, why didn't you put parens around the "g" in `\texorpdfstring{$\mathcal{L}(\gamma)$}{Lg}`?  they're there around the `(\gamma)`

Comment: @barbarabeeton The best approximation possible is left to the reader to decide.

Comment: But PDF files even support JavaScript, and the bookmark texts can be in italic, bold or color. Why can't it support images?

Comment: @Ooker I'm not saying it's impossible: but it takes someone who implements it.

Comment: Note that unicode, with the `unicode` option set for `hyperref`, allows a closer representation like ℒ(γ) for the pdf table of content. `\subsection{The classes \texorpdfstring{$\mathcal{L}(\gamma)$}{ℒ(γ)}}` works as expected, at least on my setup.  This works even if unicode characters are not accepted in math mode.

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans this is quite nice (tested by adding a `\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}` before starting my `beamer` document --- it should have a Q&A by itself, it's so useful.

Comment: I have the same problem with a $...$ environment inside the title of a beamer template. What else can I do if the \texorpdfstring{$...$} does not work?

Comment: @Diger In what sense “does not work”?

Comment: When I use it, it still shows the error.

Comment: @Diger I used an underscore in the text option: `\texorpdfstring{$t_2$}{t_2}`. I changed it to `\texorpdfstring{$t_2$}{t2}` which creates no error.

Comment: @Qbyte Maybe `\texorpdfstring{$t_2$}{t\_2}`?

Comment: @egreg Thank you this worked perfectly!

Comment: put \usepackage{hyperref} and \hypersetup{pdfauthor={Name}} source (https://albertsk.org/2019/10/10/how-to-avoid-warning-messages-from-hyperref-package-in-latex/)

Comment: @Alex Not sure what your example should show.

Comment: Does this solution change the output or does it just hide the warning (I think this information would be great to include in the answer).

Comment: @Kvothe The solution uses *different* instructions for the LaTeX part and the bookmark.

Comment: @egreg, so will the output (i.e. the .pdf) be identical or not?

Comment: @Kvothe Identical to what?

Comment: @egreg, I now understand better what the answer does and that my question was kind of bad. I meant what is the difference in output between this solution and just ignoring the warnings, which still outputs a valid pdf with something for the bookmarks. The answer is that if you do not use `\texorpdfstring` some automatic converion seems to happen which is often not good. Some things come out reasonably well in plain text. Other expressions just disappear as apparently there was no good default plaintext alternative.

Comment: Great solution!  I like the fact that it removes LaTeX warnings, which I want to keep at 0 (to get the green line at the end of my compile script :-)).