# How do you allow math-mode characters to be displayed in the PDF index?

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I have a few greek characters and subscripts in some chapter titles.  When I use `hyperref` to create a PDF index, these math-mode characters are dropped from the titles in the index.  Is it possible to get any of these rendered properly in the document index?

Maybe this depends on the PDF viewer?  If it matters, I'm using evince.

Comment: As far as I know, most viewers don't render LaTeX syntax in bookmarks / PDF index. However, `hyperref`'s `\texorpdfstring` allows you to specify a plain-text alternative to be used for the bookmarks. Example: `\section{\texorpdfstring{\frac{1}{2} = 0.5}{1/2 = 0.5}}}`.

Comment: Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/hyperref-token-not-allowed/53514#53514 might help?

Comment: This was helpful.  I was able to achieve Greek characters in the index by using e.g. `\texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{\textalpha}`.  It looks like I'm SOL for subscripts.

Comment: OK, on that basis I'm duping