# TeXShop Console messages (XeTeX)

Tags: warnings

Can someone explain what the messages in the gist at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8181888 mean? This is what TeXShop's console says when I typeset my notes. The `.tex` file of the notes is at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8181948.

Comment: run it again and everything should be fine.

Comment: @Herbert are you sure? I wouldn't expect Overfull \hbox (14014.9115pt too wide)  or Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): or ** WARNING ** Transformation matrix not invertible. to resolve on a second run?

Comment: I'm gisting three runs of a slightly different `.tex` file (just 2 or 3 more names and labels) together with the `.tex`. The three runs don't seem to have significantly altered the Console messages. To me, at least.

Comment: Here's that gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8182296.

Comment: About overfull boxes: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138/what-are-underfull-hboxes-and-vboxes-and-how-can-i-get-rid-of-them http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-does-overfull-hbox-mean

Comment: What's the purpose of doing `\hspace{500cm}`? That's simply absurd. Moreover I already told you that the value for `label=` shouldn't contain special characters such as `$` nor commands.

Comment: For the first point, `\hspace{500cm}` was a way to force a line break without the indent caused by `\par`, at a time when I didn't know it could be done by ` \\ ` since I thought that was confined to certain environments (i.e. arrays and substacks). Which is the label contaning such things you already told me not to put there @egreg?

Comment: Well, remove those construction. For the labels an example is `label=thm:defi:$d_e$ reale`; there are other similar labels.

Comment: Uh-huh that dates back to when I expected the _label_ to appear in the list of theorems and I hadn't yet found problems with tha `\mathbb R` in a label. So to _before_ you told me not to do that. If you see any, do let me know. The one mentioned I've corrected, as with another one which was `label=thm:defi:$d_{infinito}$` or something of the likes. As long as they don't give problems, I don't have time to look for them, so if either of us's eyes falls on one I'll correct it, otherwise they can stay as they are. Should that happen, could you tell me what line it is on? Thx.

Comment: As for "remove those constructions", I surely won't reuse them. I can't remove them because I definitely don't have time to look for every occurrence of them and I don't really trust the Find and Replace thing in TeXShop as it has happened to me a few times that searching a `.tex` file for things I had right before my eyes in the associated `.pdf` file returned no result.

Comment: Anyway, what about the rest of the Warnings?

Comment: They are just warnings. If you don't have time to fix them, don't. It's up to you. You don't really expect somebody else to pick through and tell you which ones might actually cause problems (by which I take it you mean something other than warnings), do you?

Comment: Yes I know they're just warnings, but since they are like Greek to me, I'd like to have a translation of those warnings to a language I understand. This way when I start a new file I can try to fix them bit by bit instead of finding myself with thousands of warnings. Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): and ** WARNING ** Transformation matrix not invertible, for example: what do they mean?

Comment: Well? What _are_ they?

Comment: For the first see if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/hyperref-token-not-allowed helps. For the second I don't really know. By the way, this would have been a better question if you included samples of the error messages in you actual question, rather than posting a link to 2000 lines of log file. You could add the link as well, but as I said somewhere else it is better if questions are self-contained, not relying on external sites. Finally, if your comment is reply to a specific user, please add `@username` in your comment, that way the user is notified.