# Automatically add \texorpdfstring for math-mode in section titles

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, hyperref, warnings

I'm receiving a ton of warnings á la "token not allowed in a pdf string", since most of my section titles contain math (see this post here: [Hyperref - Token not allowed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/hyperref-token-not-allowed) or here: [Hyperref warning - Token not allowed in a PDF string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string)).

I want to apply the solution provided to previous questions, i.e. write  `\texorpdfstring{\(math\)}{Lg}`. However, I would rather want this to be done automatically. Could the math environment (within section titles) be changed to automatically add `\textorpdfstring`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{\(I\) cast warnings but I wish I wouldnt}
\section{\texorpdfstring{\(I\)}{I} dont}
\section{Of course me neither}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What should be done with `\(\alpha=\sum_{i=0}^n \beta_i\)`?

Comment: @egreg: That is not really important, for readability in the pdf-viewer it would probably be best to just strip all characters that can't be used (i think this roughly corresponds to the behavior when I just ignore the warning). As simpler solution could just be to replace it always with "[math]" or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution is to gobble math with `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\(\fake@math}
\newcommand\fake@math{}% just for safety
\def\fake@math#1\){[math]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{\(I\) cast warnings but I wish I wouldnt}
\section{\texorpdfstring{\(I\)}{I} dont}
\section{Of course me neither}
\end{document}
```

This will replace all math formulas in `\(...\)` with `[math]`.

[image]

Doing selective replacement would need implementing a full parser.

Comment: Great. Do you know why this (or some more sophisticated version) is not implemented as the default? Rather than always displaying this warning?

Comment: @sheß I guess that Heiko wanted to leave the decision to the user.

Comment: @sheß May be you prefer `\def\fake@math#1\){\detokenize{#1}}` so you get a little more information than `[math]`. Or whatever you choose, but I mean that it contains `\detoknize{#1}` so you actually know what was in that particular math mode.

Comment: @Manuel That can be a good idea; of course it depends on what math is expected to sneak in titles.

Comment: @egreg: Can you give an example of what would cause the `\detokenize` method to fail?

Comment: @sheß Well, if I enable the `unicode` option, `\(\sum\alpha\)` outputs some strange Chinese characters in the bookmark: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0G8uY.png)