# Math character in section (book)

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I need to have sections titles with math characters but I get many warnings of this type

```
Syntax Error (155862): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (226992): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (40815): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (12396): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (12421): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (50238): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (68620): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (75689): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (82877): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (90262): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (97543): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (105073): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (112712): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (56188): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (99264): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (142277): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (185335): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (228255): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (271172): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (314086): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (356997): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (399902): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (442807): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax

Error (485709): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (528608): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (571504): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (614454): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (657347): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (700237): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (743163): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (786083): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (829009): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (871899): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (914795): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (957694): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1000590): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (1043489): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1086436): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1129329): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1172225): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1215145): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (1258041): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1300940): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1343896): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (1386795): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1429679): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1472566): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1515462): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1558409): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (1601419): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1644369): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (1687379): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (1730269): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (45694): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (153722): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (167380): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (181038): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (194696): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (42203): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (118590): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (134942): Unknown filt

er 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (46377): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (142734): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (166731): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (190728): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (214725): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (14614): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (44899): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (153774): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (175255): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (196736): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (218217): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (48489): Unknown fil

ter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (225278): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (255511): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (285744): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (315977): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (346585): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (376818): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (407409): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (437642): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (49544): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (231778): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (261756): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (291734): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (321715): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (352058): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (382036): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (412387): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (442368): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (26906): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (236487): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (276581):

Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (18428): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (222235): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (254343): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (286435): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (318527): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (350635): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (382735): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (46156): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (49127): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (51790): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (54455): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (57127): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'

Syntax Error (59796): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (62462): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (65158): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (67821): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (70481): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (73144): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (76079): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (78739): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode' Syntax Error (81405): Unknown filter 'DCTDecode'
```

I used [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306988/automatically-add-texorpdfstring-for-math-mode-in-section-titles) solution but it doesn't work for me. Maybe because I'm using a `book` class instead of an `article`?
How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\(\fake@math}
\newcommand\fake@math{}% just for safety
\def\fake@math#1\){[math]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\subsection{TE\texorpdfstring{\(_{11}\)}{11} }
\end{document}
```

This is how I'm writing the section

Comment: That doesn't really look like a TeX problem. Can you please post a MWE?

Comment: Done, but it's the same of that link

Comment: Did you try compiling the code you posted? I don't get any errors with it.

Comment: Googling the error returns a (in the meantime solved) bug of MikTeX. Is this your case?

Comment: It's possible because I compile it again with another computer where I've got MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit and it doesn't give me any warning or errors. I don't remember which version I have in the other computer, but definitely a more recent one than the 2.9.65. Thank you guys!