# resolving bibliography references in pdfcomment tooltips

Tags: beamer, biber, pdfcomment

I would like to include some bib references as tooltips in my beamer slides.  (I do NOT want a tooltip to appear for every \cite{}.)

I have started to use pdfcomment for tooltips as it seemed the simplest of those I looked at (cooltooltips, fancytooltips, pdfcomment).

I'm using Win 7, WinEdt 10, MikTeX 2.9.  I've been trying PDFLaTex + Biber + PDFLaTeX.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
  @BOOK{dav-mac-93,
    AUTHOR =       "Russell Davidson and James G. MacKinnon",
    TITLE =        "Estimation and Inference in Econometrics",
    PUBLISHER =    "Oxford University Press",
    YEAR =         "1993",
    address =      "New York",
  }
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bib}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    I want the reference in this tooltip to be resolved. \citet{dav-mac-93} 
    \pdfcomment{Resolve this reference: \citet{dav-mac-93}}

    \printbibliography
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to compile bib references in pdfcomment, or do I need another package?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key could help

Comment: thanks @samcarter.  My understanding of that thread is that it seeks to generate a tooltip for every \cite{} call.  I've clarified my OP to indicate that I don't want this: I just want to be able to include annotations whose \cite{}'s compile properly.

Comment: Most of the answers for the linked question don't do this for all cites, they define separate commands (for example `\MyTip`)  for the tooltip and leave the normal cite command unchanged.

Comment: thanks @samcarter.  Closer inspection of my .log file identified the problem (see my 'reply' below).  Thus, I didn't work through the examples in your cited question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key) to the point where I got them to work.  Thus, I wasn't able to see whether any of them did cover the same question I posed here.

Comment: The .log file identifies an error: "hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string", which pointed me to this solution, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/hyperref-token-not-allowed

A hack fix for my MWE thus edits the original \pdfcomment to read:

\pdfcomment{Resolve this reference: \texorpdfstring{\citet{dav-mac-93}}{Davidson and MacKinnon (1993)}}