# hyperref: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (Not duplicate) how to include date \today?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, date

I have been away of Beamer for a few years and I am coming back to my old notes (samples of code) that I put together and build a few new presentations.

While I was compiling the code I got the following warning:

```
hyperref: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): sample.tex
```

I know that this warning has been asked and answered here "[Hyperref warning - Token not allowed in a PDF string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string/10557)" and also here "[Hyperref - Token not allowed [duplicate]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/hyperref-token-not-allowed)".

I am raising the question on the same warning because I can not find an answer on how to include the date with the function `\today` and not produce the warning.

On my sample of code if I include the function `\today` I get the warning, if I remove the function and I add manually the date (e.g. 23-04-2018) the code compiles just fine.

**sample.tex** (**Update 2:** Minimal working example)

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm (For special Fonts)

\author[First Last Name]{Date: \today} % (optional, for multiple authors)

\begin{document}
  \titlepage
\end{document}
```

So my question, is there any way to include the `\today` function without getting the warning? I do not want to supress the warning I know that there is there for a reason. I am asking if anyone sees if I am doing something wrong and know any work around other than updating manual the date.

Comment: @campa, I have updated the sample of code. You are right, actually I needed only 9 lines. The reason that I added all the lines was to add simply all the headers and footers that I am using. Regarding why I am putting the `\today` function inside the author. The only reason that I am doing so, is because the auto produced date is really far in the page and by removing vertical white space it destroys the rest of the alignments.

Comment: Thanks for the update! One more hint: `beamer` loads also `hyperref` by default, so you can delete one more line `:-)`

Comment: @campa, nice trick. I has no clue about that. Thanks for the tip. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default definition of `\today` is expandable, but loading `beamer` changes it:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm (For special Fonts)

\show\today

\author[First Last Name]{Date: \today} % (optional, for multiple authors)

\begin{document}
  \titlepage
\end{document}
```

This shows the definition of `\today`:

```
> \today=macro:
->\ifcase \month \or \translate {January}\or \translate {February}\or \translat
e {March}\or \translate {April}\or \translate {May}\or \translate {June}\or \tr
anslate {July}\or \translate {August}\or \translate {September}\or \translate {
October}\or \translate {November}\or \translate {December}\fi \space \number \d
ay , \number \year .
l.4 \show\today
```

The `\translate` command is robust and so can't expand and it's that that's causing the problem. A simple solution is to load [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2), which changes `\today` back to being expandable:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm (For special Fonts)

\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}

\author[First Last Name]{Date: \today} % (optional, for multiple authors)

\begin{document}
  \titlepage
\end{document}
```

This example also requires [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) which is installed separately.

Comment: it works like a charm. Thanks for providing also sample of the code and analysis to the solution. :)