# Automatically replace underscore with \textunderscore for PDF strings, e.g. with \pdfstringdefDisableCommands

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

Is it possible to mimic the output of

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{$x_1$}{x\_1}}
```

using `\section{$x_1$}` and `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{...}` ? I've only seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537449/removing-math-shift/590978#590978), which tries to do something similar, but it doesn't work (as they acknowledge). I'm not too concerned about warnings; I just want `x_1` to appear in the bookmarks for the PDF, while not having `\texorpdfstring{...}{...}` for every instance of an underline.

---

MWE for the error generated by tikz when using @StevenB.Segletes's first solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{tikz} % OK

\let\svus_
\catcode`\_=\active
\gdef_{\texorpdfstring{\svus}{\string_}}

%%%    
% pgfmathparser.code.tex
% ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
% <to be read again> 
%                    \svus 
% l.251 ...mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
% \usepackage{tikz}    
%%%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{$x_1$}

Document math, $a^3_1$ should be no problem

\section{$y_1$}

Does This\_work?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: well personnally I think it would look nicer in the bookmarks if you used `\section{\texorpdfstring{$x_1$}{x₁}}`, but it wouldn't be trivial to automate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that hyperref warns you about the subscript character
with something like

> ```
> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
> (hyperref)                removing `subscript' on input line 33.
> ```

So clearly hyperref knows that it encounters a subscript character.
All you need to do is to tell hyperref that, the next time you see `_`,
instead of a warning, you put that character into the pdf toc.

The following code does that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\subscripttext{subscript}
\def\HyPsd@CatcodeWarning#1{%
  \def\argone{#1}
  \ifx\subscripttext\argone
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\HyPsd@String\expandafter{\HyPsd@String_}%
  \else
    \HyPsd@Warning{%
      Token not allowed in a PDF string (%
      \ifHy@unicode
        Unicode%
      \else
        PDFDocEncoding%
      \fi
      ):%
      \MessageBreak removing `\HyPsd@RemoveCmdPrefix#1'%
    }%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{$x_1$}
    Document math, $a^3_1$ should be no problem
\section{$y_1$}
    Does This\_work?

\end{document}
```

This approach allows you to not setting the catcode of `_`.
There are only this many special characters
and a bunch of packages are competing with each other
for a chance to define the activated characters.
Ti*k*Z, as you noticed, is an expert in that sort.

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to this one since it uses the tools provided by hyperref. Should there be a `\makeatother` after the last `\def` block?

Comment: Yes there should be a `\makeatother`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the underscore math active.

You'll get warnings

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 17.
```

but the output will be as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz} % OK
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~\sb}%
  \mathcode`_="8000
  \catcode`_=12
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{$x_1$}

Document math, $a^3_1$ should be no problem

\section{$y_1$}

This\_works and also_this.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's similar

Answer (score 2):

Here I make `_` active to accomplish it.  Not sure if that works for your need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\svus_
\catcode`\_=\active
\gdef_{\texorpdfstring{\svus}{\string_}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$x_1$}

Document math, $a^3_1$ should be no problem

\section{$y_1$}

Does This\_work?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps a better way is to use `\mathcode`, so that `_` is not active, but catcode-12 inside the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\svus_
\mathcode\number`\_="8000
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_ \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}%
  {\texorpdfstring{\svus}{\string_}}
\catcode`\_=12
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{$x_1$}

Document math, $a^3_1$ should be no problem

\section{$y_1$}

Does This\_work?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, they both seem to work in my use case. When loading `tikz` after the first solution, it complains with `Missing \endcsname inserted.` on `\svus`. I've added a MWE for that error in the original post, feel free to copy it if you want to add an explanation.