# Remove A before Appendix in article using appendices package

Tags: formatting, appendices

If this question has been asked before and answered, I will remove it.

Consider the following output:

[image]

I'd like to remove the A, and likewise for all subsections following that appendix (there is only a single appendix). I've tried using `\appendix` command instead, but it doesn't insert "Appendix" and the space between "Appendix" and "Code" on default, both of which I'd like to keep. The output was produced with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}


\begin{appendices}
\section{Code}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the "numbers" of subsections in the appendix section supposed to look like? "A.1", "A.2", etc.; "1", "2", etc.; "a", "b", etc.' or something else? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, should have included it. I guess simply 1,2, etc. Since there is none on the appendix, maybe even no numbering at all, which would be simply giving it a star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something how this? I have used `\section*{\appendixname\, Code}` with a bit of space `\,` (or you can put `\quad`) because the two words are very close to each other that they seem to be united.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}


\begin{appendices}
\section*{\appendixname\, Code}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the easy solution. ```\quad``` seems to do it.

Comment: However, how does one keep the appendix in the table of contents? Putting a star in the section command seems to make it vanish.

Comment: @schn I honestly don't know :-( sorry. I only answered your question by looking at the manual.

Comment: I used ```\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\appendixname \quad Code}``` and it works, however I get a hyperref warning saying that "token not allowed in a PDF string", which I think has something to do with using ```\quad```.

Comment: @schn If you have a bit of time look this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/hyperref-token-not-allowed

Comment: @schn Please, can you switch your check mark to the Mico best answer? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments and suggestions:

- I wouldn't use '1', '2', etc to denote the *sub*section numbers in the appendix, as that will needlessly invite confusion as the sections in the main body of the document are numbered '1', '2, etc as well.
- Hence, I'd like to suggest that you keep the default numbering of the subsections in the appendix, viz., 'A.1', 'A.2', etc.
- The code below shows how to modify the appearance of the appendix-level section header ("Code") in a way that doesn't mess the rest of the numbering system.
- You may also want to modify the `\appendix` command to write a header such as "Appendix Material" to the header file.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\apptocmd\appendix{%
    \newcommand\section@cntformat{\appendixname:\ }
    \addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip\noindent\textbf{Appendix Material}\par}
    {}{}}
\makeatother
    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\bigskip\hrule

\section{Hello}
\subsection{Uno}
\subsection{Due}

\appendix
\section{Code}
\subsection{One}
\subsection{Two}

\end{document}
```