# How to display a bold math symbol in a subsection-level header

Tags: sectioning, bold, boldsymbol

i have a subsection named

```
\subsection{$\Lambda$CDM}
```

is there a way to show `\Lambda`  as a bold symbol?
I have tried with `\bm{}`

```
\subsection{$\bm{\Lambda}$CDM}
```

but I got errors  and textbf doesn't seem to help

Comment: But, isn't the whole title of a `\subsection` bold by default?

Comment: A statement such as "I got errors" is not helpful -- unless a reader is blessed with unusually keen psychic divination powers. (Sadly, I'm not in that august set.) *Which* error(s) did you get?

Comment: @Mico it absolutely annihilated my pdf with  a long list of  pratically every kind of possible error  that it would take an impractical amount of time to write xD

Comment: @Alucard - Generally, the very first error is the most important one. (Downstream error messages can be mostly gibberish.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\boldmath` command, to be issued *before* you enter math mode, is your friend here, as in

```
\subsection{\boldmath $\Lambda$CDM}
```

[image]

However, if your document features a table of contents, you should write

```
\subsection[$\Lambda$CDM]{\boldmath $\Lambda$CDM}
```

in order to avoid getting `\Lambda` typeset in bold in the ToC entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\stepcounter{section}
\subsection{\boldmath $\Lambda$CDM}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works but now i get "Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `math shift' on input line 385." and 'Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\Lambda' on input line 385.' . is there a way to avoid this warnings?

Comment: @Alucard - Please see the posting [Hyperref - Token not allowed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53513/5001) for information on what to do to get rid of this warning message. Incidentally, your phrasing "...but now I get..." is somewhat misleading. The `hyperref`-related warning message you mention as getting now is actually entirely orthogonal to the main issue of your query. Indeed, the "token not allowed" warning message must have been there as soon as you included `$\Lambda$` in the argument of `\subsection`. You may have simply missed that it was there until just now...