# How to correctly use a cite command in a chapter/section title? Error Message: Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, section-titles, token

I'm using a `\textcite{key}` command in my section name/title in order to describe there the studies made by this specific author. However, I'm receiving the warning message "Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\textcite' on input line 25".

I searched the internet for this warning, however, I only found solutions for some unicode-character problems. Are those solutions also applicable for my problem? See for example here: [Hyperref - Token not allowed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53513/316681)

Or does there exist another proper workaround for this problem?

Best regards,
Aline

[image: Hyperref Warning]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{test,
  title={Testing Title},
  author={Testperson, Some},
  year={2024},
  publisher={Some Publisher},
  location = {Anywhere}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
  sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{\textcite{test}}


I am citing \textcite{test}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried \protect\textcite... ?

Comment: `\textcite` is robust and hyperref has no chance to expand it for the bookmarks. You will have to give it some fallback e.g. `\section{\texorpdfstring{\textcite{test}}{Testperson}}`

Comment: @Mane32: yes, I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that works - thanks!