# hyperref warning caused by Beamer appendix

Tags: beamer, hyperref, warnings

The code below results in the following warning: "Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing '\translate' on input line 16."

(Note: line 16 is the blank line immediately following `\appendix`.)

This warning occurs even if I remove the supplemental slide and leave `\appendix` as the last line before `\end{document}`. The warning does not occur if I remove the appendix entirely. The .pdf file produced is apparently correct, but I'd like to be able to include an appendix without encountering the warning.

I looked through the previously answered questions and found references to the `\texorpdfstring` command, but I couldn't seem make it work in this case. Has anyone found a solution, or can anyone point me to a previously answered question that I may have missed? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{First Section} 
\begin{frame}\frametitle{First Section} 
This is a slide.
\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Supplemental Material} 
This is a supplemental slide.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is the definition of `\appendix` in `beamerbasesection.sty` which uses `\part{\appendixname}` and `\appendixname` is defined in `beamerbasemisc.sty` as `\translate{Appendix}`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can work around this warning by using

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}


\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{First Section} 
\begin{frame}\frametitle{First Section} 
This is a slide.
\end{frame}

\appendix

\section{Appendix}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Supplemental Material} 
This is a supplemental slide.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

The Reason for the warning was explained in [@Gonzalo Medina's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) comment

> The problem is the definition of \appendix in beamerbasesection.sty which uses \part{\appendixname} and \appendixname is defined in beamerbasemisc.sty as \translate{Appendix}

**Related issue on github:**

https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/449

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll vote your answer up when (if) I get to 15 reputation points.

Comment: If you want to, you can add to your answer the reason for the warning (I gave it in a comment to the question).

Answer (score 6):

Macro `\translate` is defined in package `translator`. It is defined with an optional argument with many assignments in the implementation. Therefore it is not expandable and cannot be used in bookmarks this way.

The following code provides `\bkmtranslate`, a poor man's definition of `\translate` without support for an optional argument. Also the language search of the original `\translate` is not implemented. Instead, the language is defined as macro `\bkmtranslateto`. The default is `\languagename`. If the translation is not found, then the argument is used without modification, the same behavior as the original `\translate` except, that the original `\translate` can extend the search to more than one language.

`\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` is used to install `\bkmtranslate` as replacement for `\translate` in the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\bkmtranslateto}{\languagename}
\newcommand*{\bkmtranslate}[1]{%
  \ifcsname tr@@@\bkmtranslateto @#1\endcsname
    \csname tr@@@\bkmtranslateto @#1\endcsname
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\translate\bkmtranslate}
\makeatother

\usepackage{bookmark}% not needed here, but faster bookmark updates
```

Answer (score 3):

... it's an old question, but I thought it might be worth mentioning that this
can also be solved by the suggestion mentioned here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330980/172810

... e.g. simply add this to your preamble:

```tex
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
\def\translate#1{#1}%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the babel package also resolves the issue as `\translate{Appendix}` produces a decent name.