# Teaching Hyperref about \char

Tags: xetex, errors, hyperref

If I use `\char` in a section title, hyperref gives we either warnings or errors:

- This breaks compilation:

  ```
  \subsection{Some thoughts about {\char`\\} {\char`\^} {\char`\$} {\char`\~} 
              {\char`\%} {\char`\&} {\char`\{} {\char`\}} {\char`\_} {\char`\#}}
  ```

  ```
  ./minimal.tex:9: Argument of \PU\^ has an extra }.
  <inserted text> 
              \par
  ```
- This compiles, with warnings:

  ```
  \subsection{Some thoughts about {\char`\\} {\char`\$} 
              {\char`\%} {\char`\&} {\char`\{} {\char`\}} {\char`\_} {\char`\#}}
  ```

  ```
  Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
  (hyperref)                removing `\char' on input line 9.
  ```

**Can I teach hyperref about `\char`, so as to get `Some thoughts about \^&~%&{}_#` in my PDF bookmarks?**

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Some thoughts about {\char`\\} {\char`\^} {\char`\$} {\char`\~} {\char`\%} {\char`\&} {\char`\{} {\char`\}} {\char`\_} {\char`\#}}
\end{document}
```

I am aware of [Hyperref warning - Token not allowed in a PDF string](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string) and the `\texorpdfstring` command, but `\texorpdfstring` is confused about `\char` as well.  I am also aware of other ways to quote individual characters (`\textasciitilde` etc.), but I would rather avoid them, if possible: I have trouble remembering them, and parts of my document are automatically exported from other formats.

Comment: just don't use `\char` here (see your other question:-)

Comment: Exactly: I asked that other qestion for this reason. But is there really no way? Some of this code is auto-generated, and I'd love to tweak things on the LaTeX thing instead of patching a compiler.

Comment: ``\texorpdfstring{\char`\^}{caret}``?

Answer (score 4):

Use `texorpdfstring` to provide an alternative definition for `hyperref`.  To have a caret showing up in the PDF bookmarks, use `\^{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{\char`\^}{\^{}}}
\end{document}
```