# Compilation hangs when using packages silence and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, silence

As I was working on a document, I temporarily put some mathematical formulae with `\mathscr` in a section title. That didn't pose me any problem until the moment I tried to use both packages `silence` and `hyperref`, at which point compilation simply hung up. I've since found a way around the problem that fits my need, but I'm still curious as to why having `silence` or `hyperref` alone works fine, while having both interupts the compilation?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

%%%% this alone works
%\usepackage{silence}
%%%% this alone also works
%\usepackage{hyperref}

%%%% this hangs compilation
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\section{Testing $\mathscr A$}
lorem

\end{document}
```

I'm currently using `pdflatex` to produce a PDF output.

Note: if anyone has a similar problem, I'm told you should avoid mathematical formulae in section titles, and if you really have to, try using `\texorpdfstring{math}{replacement text}`.
EDIT: As [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) commented, a better workaround is "to disable `\mathscr` when generating bookmark strings" with
`\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\mathscr\relax}`.
That way, whenever `\mathscr` was used in a section title, it will be ignored, whereas `\texorpdfstring{}{}` requires you to specify replacement text every single time.

Comment: Given that the purpose of the `silence` package is just to filter out some error messages by interfering with the messaging system, this can be considered a bug of `silence`. So I suggest to remove the `silence` package if it causes troubles. The trigger is a warning by the hyperref package that something about `\mathscr` will be ignored, basically harmless.

Comment: `\mathscr` can be ignored, when generating bookmark strings: `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\mathscr\relax}`

Comment: Someone care to explain why this is a duplicate? The workaround is the same, but [this other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string) doesn't really answer mine...