# Ways to avoid 'Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string' warning

Tags: hyperref

I know that this question was asked [almost 80 times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Package+hyperref+Warning%3A+Token+not+allowed+in+a+PDF+string) and that the best solution is probably to use `\texorpdfstring{...}{...}` but I don't want to a mess inside the document so I was thinking of [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330980/89662).

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\${}%
  \def\alpha{alpha}%
}
```

But this doesn't change the fact that

```
\section{$\alpha$}
```

gives the warning

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): (hyperref) removing `math shift' [...]

So the question is: Can I use `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{...}` to avoid using `\texorpdfstring{...}{...}` when handling math in sections?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here I use `\(...\)` in lieu of `$...$`.  Warnings avoided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
%  \def${}%
  \def\alpha{alpha}%
  \def\({}%
  \def\){}%
  \def\texttt#1{<#1>}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{\texttt{xyz}\(\alpha\)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or get a bit more descriptive in the replacement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\alpha{alpha}%
  \def\({Math:[}%
  \def\){]}%
  \def\texttt#1{<#1>}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{\texttt{xyz}\(\alpha\)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\alpha` is supported by option `psdextra` and the bookmark needs to be in Unicode: `\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref}`. Without option `psdextra` the macro `\textalpha` can be used (option `unicode` or `pdfencoding=auto` is still needed).

Answer (score 1):

Since I’m using `unicode-math` package, I actually do this in my works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand\pdfmath[1]{\texorpdfstring{$#1$}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{\pdfmath{α}}
\end{document}
```

Or, as Heiko Oberdiek proposed if you’re not into `unicode-math`, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}
\newcommand\pdfmath[1]{\texorpdfstring{$#1$}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{\pdfmath{\alpha}}
\end{document}
```

It’s slightly better than plain `\texorpdfstring` though not ideal. So all of that is only if like me you don’t like `\(` and `\)` as delimiting your math (but also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513/56823 and especially comments below about this), else you would better go with Steven + Heiko answers. ;)