# Can I put maths symbol for example: $\boldsymbol{e}$ in Chapter title?

Tags: hyperref, packages, mathspec

I wish to put maths symbol in my Chapter title, but when I run Overleaf, it give `warning`, but not `error`.

It said 
`Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string`

[image]

My WME:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

\chapter{The value of $\boldsymbol{e}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Nasser, I have no idea how to provide a MWE, because the error of compilation is because of my whole thesis code.

Comment: AN example of MWE: `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The value of $\boldsymbol{e}$}
\end{document}
`, which works fine ...

Comment: @Zarko Read the warning message: the warning is produced by hyperref. In addition to my answer, see this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430876/ways-to-avoid-package-hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string-warn?rq=1

Comment: Actually just adding the hyperref package to Zarko's code will produce the issue.

Comment: amsmath and `\boldsymbol` are not required. They just make the problem worse, because the bookmark actually contains the hidden pmb generated by boldsymbol.

Comment: @Nasser, thanks. Now I know is related to `hypererlink` issue and i edit my question to include MWE. I have no idea how i can create a MWE for a simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the warning seems to have to do with the auto-generated bookmarks from the hyperref package. Even just using math mode will cause some warnings in the log. `\boldsymbol` makes a mess.

The easiest way to fix the problem is

```
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{The value of $\boldsymbol{e}$}{The value of e}}
```

The macro `\texorpdfstring` will use the first argument for the PDF contents, and the second argument for the bookmarks. Read more in section 4.1.2 of the documentation of the `hyperref` package.

P.S.

1. You should use `\boldmath` or `\bm` instead. The spacing produced by `\boldsymbol` is bad in some cases. A note of warning that using `\bm` without `\texorpdfstring` produces a fatal error.
2. if you manually specify a different TOC heading in the optional argument to `\chapter`, `\section`, etc. (eg. to unbold the math), `\texorpdfstring` goes in the optional argument, not the main argument.

Comment: thanks. Would I able to add `\ref` in my `Chapter/Section` heading? I tried `\section{\texorpdfstring{Texting {\sffamily x} $/$ {\sffamily x}$^{T}${\sffamily B}{\sffamily x}. A proof of equation \ref{equationforappendix}}}
{Texting {x} / {x}^{T}{B}{x}. A proof of equation \ref{equationforappendix}}` But it seemed not working. I can post a new question if you need it.