# How to format a beamer title with two names and one institution

Tags: beamer, titles, author

I would like to be able to format my beamer title page such that it includes the name of an author and module leader, but with one institution name. So the typical way of inserting two author names with the superscripts will not do in this case. In specific this is whay I envision for the layout to be like:[image]

However I am struggling to get that as there only seem to be limited option in terms of inserting the authors names. This beamer I know that there must be a way however I don't know how.

This is the basic code that I am currently working on

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Introduction to Torsional Vibrations}
\subtitle{NM952 -- Lecture 1}

\author{Name}

\institute{Department}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Introduction to Torsional Vibrations}
\subtitle{NM952 -- Lecture 1}

\author{%
    \texorpdfstring{\parbox{45mm}{\centering Author \\ Author 1 \\ \url{author1@email.com}}}{Author 1} \and 
    \texorpdfstring{\parbox{45mm}{\centering Module Leader \\ Author 2 \\ \url{author2@email.com}}}{Author 2}%
}

\institute{University}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\normalsize}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame. This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What does this compicated code do? The macro `\texorpdfstring` makes sure that the `hyperref` package only sees `Author 1 \and Author 2` and not the other stuff that is, however, needed to properly align all the information. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10557/47927) for more details.

Apart from that, I essentially just placed two `\parbox`es of 40mm width each next to each other. Inside, I placed all the information preceded by a `\centering` macro to make it centered. That's about it.

To change the font size for the `\institution`, you can use `\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\normalsize}`. And to hide the date, simply use `\date{}`.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful