# How to add advisors to title page in a predefined theme

Tags: beamer, titles, beamer-metropolis

I am using the metropolis theme to create a beamer presentation. I would like to include in the title page, on the left, my name as main author, and on the right, a column named "advisors" with the name of my advisors. Something like this image:

[image]

This is a very basic MWE without the advisors part:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{\textbf{Title}}
\author{Main author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I am struggling on how to include the advisors column here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a [quite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/393310/47927) [common](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163190/47927) [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622753/47927). Anyways, you could try with:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{\textbf{Title}}
\author[Author names]{%
    \parbox[t]{7cm}{%
        \textbf{Author} \\
        Affiliation
    }%
    \parbox[t]{7cm}{%
        \textbf{Advisors} \\
        1st Advisor \\
        2nd Advisor
    }%
}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you should use the optional argument for `\author` to include a non-styled version of the authors' names.