# Problem adding subscripts and superscripts

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cursive text after _](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/cursive-text-after)

I need to have some subscripted and superscripted text in my thesis document. But when I try to do it the way as H_{2O} or S^{2}. I get an error at that point and if I compile it anyway I get text with so white spaces for the rest of the line. Like,

```
H_{2O}helloworldwhyisthishappening
```

Do I need to use some package to have this functionality? I thought it was standard latex. Or may be it is due to conflict with some package. I'm using the university template so don't quite understand what the problem is. I have put the header section where the packages are called below. Please help.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{verbatim}    
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy,amsmath} 
\usepackage{listings}
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1013/2975) which is about the same thing.

Answer (score 24):

If you are typesetting chemical formula, look up the [mhchem](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package. This allows you to typeset chemical formulae easily.

For example: `\ce{CO2}` has the "2" as a subscript. Neat.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{H2SO4}
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image: H2SO4]

Comment: +1 For chemical formula this is the way to go (Sorry Seamus, I'm already out of votes for today). My answer was more about the general case.

Comment: One could also use the package `chemmacros` and its command `\ch` (not that there's anything wrong with `mhchem` :) )

Comment: The `chemmacros` package looks a lot more powerful than `mhchem`, but for what was required for this question, I think `mhchem` is the simpler, smaller, cheaper option.

Answer (score 7):

The `_` and `^` character only work in math-mode. For text you need to use `\textsubscript` (needs the `fixltx2e` package) and `\textsuperscript` instead.

The reason why all the whitespace after `H_{2O}` is missing is that TeX changing into math-mode at the `_` and then all the letters afterwards are set as variables. Also I think you mean `H_{2}O` (BTW: the braces can be skipped when they include only one character).

Answer (score 2):

No special package but you need to be in math-mode. Use `$ $` or `\ensuremath{}`.

Comment: This is not a good solution. You shouldn't use mathmode for things that aren't maths. There is a textsubscript option mentioned in a different answer that is the Right Way to do this...

Comment: @Seamus: is this the reason, why you never use footnotes ;-)

Comment: @Herbert Is that how footnotes work? Huh. I am going to start boycotting footnotes now! But seriously, since footnotes are marked up "semantically" it's ok, even if they abuse mathmode internally...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest ways I have found to include super- and subscripts in text mode are shown below.  The example is the chemical formula for silicon dioxide:

Method 1:

```
$\rm SiO_2$
```

Method 2:

```
SiO$_2$
```

I am using MikTeX 2.4 and `dvips` + `ps2pdf`, and my PDF output looks good: The letters are definitely in text mode, not math, and the results of the two methods look the same in PDF.

An addendum: If the super- or subscript is an expression, do the following:

C$*n$H$*{2n+2}$

which yields the chemical formula for polyethylene.

Comment: Regarding your use of `\rm`, please read: [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT). Also, MiKTeX 2.4 is *heavily* outdated. Consider an [upgrade to the most current version](http://miktex.org/download) (MiKTeX 2.9).

Comment: Thanks for the comment on using \rm, but I really don't need to be told that the latest version of MiKTeX is 2.9. I practice "minimal computing": Whatever gets the job done with the least amount of overhead.