# How do I typeset chemical formulae in the achemso package or related packages?

Tags: achemso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem adding subscripts and superscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/problem-adding-subscripts-and-superscripts)

I am using the `achemso` package to typeset my research report in LaTeX.  [This achemso package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso) provides the correct section, etc. formatting in the style of the American Chemical Society (ACS).  However, in the documentation, I do not see how to typeset simple, in-line, text-based chemical formulae.  Do you know if I need to use an additional package to accomplish this?

For example, I would like to typeset a sentence like:

The ion we investigated is PO4-.

I could do:

```
The ion we investigated is $PO_4^-$.
```

But this makes the letters PO italicized, like math symbols.  Instead, I would like the PO to be textual.  Is there a chemistry-related package with which I can do this?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11416/problem-adding-subscripts-and-superscripts: `mhchem` is your friend.

Comment: There's also [`bpchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bpchem) that may be of interest.