# Cursive text after _

Tags: formatting

I would like to write H2O with a small 2 below the H.

```
H_2 O (water)
```

However, all text after _2 becomes cursive. It appear that something obvious is wrong but, I cant find what it is.

Anyone how have had the same problem?

Comment: it is hard to tell, however, the `_` needs to be in a math mode to be subscripted. So do `H$_2$O`.

Comment: Besides the fact that `_` is only valid in math-mode (and LaTeX probably used math-mode from `_2` on and didn’t know where to stop), `\textsubscript{2}` also works mostly. If you find yourself often using chemical formulae you might be interested in [certain packages](http://www.ctan.org/topic/chemistry).

Comment: @RollerBoy, you probably (as Gonzalo also indicates) use the mhchem package. It is much inferior in use and can do a lot of stuff! :)

Answer (score 13):

Hard to tell without seeing the actual code you are using; anyways, I'd suggest you the [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{H2O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{H2O}

\end{document}
```

However, for just one or two formulae, using a package might be overkill, and you could simply say something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{H}_2\mathrm{O}$

\end{document}
```

Or using a command, as **cgnieder** suggested,

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chem{H_2O}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar with [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) (`\ch{H2O}`). The package is probably overkill, though, if one only needs one or two chemical formulas.

Comment: I not having too much chemical formulas to write so $_2$ will do, but anyway Thanks

Comment: @RollerBoy I added another options to my answer; I wouldn't use just `$_2$` please see my last example.

Comment: @RollerBoy how about saying `\newcommand*\chem[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}` in the preamble and then use it like `\chem{H_2O}`?

Comment: @cgnieder I've added your two suggestions to my answer; thank you!

Comment: @cgnieder This is indeed a place where `\ensuremath` can be really useful.

Comment: @egreg They're rare but there _are_ use cases ;)