# Alignment of text in siunitx package

Tags: tables, siunitx

I made a table using `siunitx` package. In one of the column there is text depicting chemical formulae. Is it possible to **align only this column to the left.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{ Comparison of new data to previously reported \label{Transition_delG_HD} }
\begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSS}
    \toprule

    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{${\alpha}$} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\beta$}   \\ \cline{2-4} \cline{6-8} 
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Our$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Ref. $} &  {$\Delta$} & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Our$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$Ref. $} & {$\Delta$}\\  \cline{2-4} \cline{6-8}

         {C\textsubscript{2}H\textsubscript{5}OH}     & 25    & 25.5  & -0.5  &       & 25    & 25.5  & -0.5 \\
            {CH\textsubscript{3}OH}       & 26    & 26.12 & -0.12 &       & 26    & 26.12 & -0.12 \\
          {H\textsubscript{2}O}        & 24    & 24.23 & -0.23 &       & 24    & 24.23 & -0.23 \\
            {HF}        & 24    & 24.23 & -0.23 &       & 24    & 24.23 & -0.23 \\


    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{$\Delta^{a}$ : From Ref. 5} \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Following image shows the issue.
[image: Table made by siunitx]

The left-most column with the chemical formulae, I was hoping it can be left aligned.

Comment: Whya re you even using `S` for that column, there is only text, just use `l`

Comment: @daleif :   Oh, I did not know that. Thanks. Solved .

Comment: Also why is `Our` and `Ref.` in math mode in the headers? That looks odd. Plus use `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline` better spacing (just forget about `\hline` and `\cline`)

Comment: also, if you are using a lot of chemical formulas in your paper, I would suggest you look into the `mhchem` package.

Comment: Thank you for the very very useful suggestions. I am new to latex and learning. yay !

Comment: @ArTourter even if it is only those four chemical formulas I'd at least use some simple macro like I already suggested here: [Typesetting chemical element names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145860/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some improvements to your table: you don't need an empty column to have distinct `\cline`s if you replace them with `\cmidrule`s and crop them on both sides. Also, as daleif pointed, the first column can to be left-aligned rather than `S` type. You have three different number formats for your `S` columns, and it's better to differentiate them. Last, don't end a tabular by a `\\`: it adds an unwanted vertical spacing.

I loaded the `cellspace` package to give some vertical padding to cells in the first column; the column specifier has to be prefixed with the letter `S` in general, and `C`if `siunitx`, as here, is loaded. I aalso loade the `chemformula` to simplify typing of chemical compounds.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{ Comparison of new data to previously reported \label{Transition_delG_HD} }
\begin{tabular}{Cl*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=-1.2]}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{${\alpha}$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$\beta$} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & {Our} & {Ref. } & {$\Delta$} & {Our} & {Ref.} & {$\Delta$}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
         \ch{C2H5OH} & 25 & 25.5 & -0.5 & 25 & 25.5 & -0.5 \\
            \ch{CH3OH} & 26 & 26.12 & -0.12 & 26 & 26.12 & -0.12 \\
          \ch{H2O} & 24 & 24.23 & -0.23 & 24 & 24.23 & -0.23 \\
            HF & 24 & 24.23 & -0.23 & 24 & 24.23 & -0.23 \\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize$\Delta^{a}$ : From Ref. 5}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have questions. First.  `\begin{tabular}{Cl*{2}{S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=-1.2]}}`  what does the number after   `table-format` defines ?     Second question.  What is defined by the `(lr)` in  `\cmidrule(lr){5-7}` ?

Comment: First question: in the preamble of a table, *{2}{…}` denotes the number of repetitions of a pattern (note I mention only 3`S`). Second question: (lr) stipulates cropping the rule on the left and on the right. The amount of cropping can be changed (see the documentation of `booktabs` for details).

Comment: Not really an issue but I'd also write `\ch{HF}`…

Comment: @clemens: I wondered, but as there was no index… I know, I may be inconsistent at times ;o)

Comment: Dear Bernard. I have never seen a column specification "Cl". Can you tell me where is it from?

Comment: @MorZahavi: It is explained in the answer: the specifier is actually the usual `l`, and there's a pre-specifier to ensure a minimal vertical padding of the cells in this column. This pre-specifer, defined by the `cellspace` package, is by default the letter `S`, but as the  `siunitx` package is also loaded and it already defines an `S` column type, the pre-specifier is by default changed to the  letter `C`, but you can use another letter, loading the package with the option `[column=some other letter]`. An example is given in the (short) documentation.