# siunitx squashing columns

Tags: tables, siunitx, alignment

I have a table that I've formatted like this:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
            \hline
        {Combo} &   {$|r|>0.5$} &   {$n>100$}   &   {$r^2n$} \\
        \hline
        {U-V}   &   0.558545    &   11640   &   3631.36 \\
        {U-R}   &   0.567270    &   11632   &   3743.12 \\
        {U-I}   &   0.579188    &   11626   &   3900.04 \\
        {U-J}   &   0.536106    &   3709    &   1066 \\
        {U-K}   &   0.535644    &   3730    &   1070.19 \\
        {B-V}   &   0.580019    &   11884   &   3998.04 \\
        {B-R}   &   0.574867    &   11763   &   3887.34 \\
        {B-I}   &   0.591288    &   11749   &   4107.7 \\
        {V-U}   &   -0.558545   &   11640   &   3631.36 \\
        {V-B}   &   -0.580019   &   11884   &   3998.04 \\
        {R-U}   &   -0.567270   &   11632   &   3743.12 \\
        {R-B}   &   -0.574867   &   11763   &   3887.34 \\
        {R-W2}  &   -0.535443   &   4022    &   1153.1 \\
        {I-U}   &   -0.579188   &   11626   &   3900.04 \\
        {I-B}   &   -0.591288   &   11749   &   4107.7 \\
        {I-W2}  &   -0.574056   &   4020    &   1324.75 \\
        {J-U}   &   -0.536106   &   3709    &   1066 \\
        {J-W2}  &   -0.577232   &   1943    &   647.401 \\
        {K-U}   &   -0.535644   &   3730    &   1070.19 \\
        {K-W1}  &   -0.512554   &   1938    &   509.136 \\
        {K-W2}  &   -0.591156   &   1960    &   684.953 \\
        {W1-K}  &   0.512554    &   1938    &   509.136 \\
        {W2-R}  &   0.535443    &   4022    &   1153.1 \\
        {W2-I}  &   0.574056    &   4020    &   1324.75 \\
        {W2-J}  &   0.577232    &   1943    &   647.401 \\
        {W2-K}  &   0.591156    &   1960    &   684.953 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption[Best photometric colours from the MgII dataset]{Photometric colours with highest r-value from the MgII dataset.}
\label{table:MgII_colours}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

to produce:

[image]

but I need the numerical columns aligned on the decimal points. From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314703/alignment-of-text-in-siunitx-package) I tried formatting it as

```
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{
                        @{}
            l
            S[table-format=1.2]
            S[table-format=1.2]
            S[table-format=2.3]         
                        @{}
        }
        \hline
        {Combo} &   {$|r|>0.5$} &   {$n>100$}   &   {$r^2n$} \\
        \hline
        {U-V}   &   0.558545    &   11640   &   3631.36 \\
        {U-R}   &   0.567270    &   11632   &   3743.12 \\
        {U-I}   &   0.579188    &   11626   &   3900.04 \\
        {U-J}   &   0.536106    &   3709    &   1066 \\
        {U-K}   &   0.535644    &   3730    &   1070.19 \\
        {B-V}   &   0.580019    &   11884   &   3998.04 \\
        {B-R}   &   0.574867    &   11763   &   3887.34 \\
        {B-I}   &   0.591288    &   11749   &   4107.7 \\
        {V-U}   &   -0.558545   &   11640   &   3631.36 \\
        {V-B}   &   -0.580019   &   11884   &   3998.04 \\
        {R-U}   &   -0.567270   &   11632   &   3743.12 \\
        {R-B}   &   -0.574867   &   11763   &   3887.34 \\
        {R-W2}  &   -0.535443   &   4022    &   1153.1 \\
        {I-U}   &   -0.579188   &   11626   &   3900.04 \\
        {I-B}   &   -0.591288   &   11749   &   4107.7 \\
        {I-W2}  &   -0.574056   &   4020    &   1324.75 \\
        {J-U}   &   -0.536106   &   3709    &   1066 \\
        {J-W2}  &   -0.577232   &   1943    &   647.401 \\
        {K-U}   &   -0.535644   &   3730    &   1070.19 \\
        {K-W1}  &   -0.512554   &   1938    &   509.136 \\
        {K-W2}  &   -0.591156   &   1960    &   684.953 \\
        {W1-K}  &   0.512554    &   1938    &   509.136 \\
        {W2-R}  &   0.535443    &   4022    &   1153.1 \\
        {W2-I}  &   0.574056    &   4020    &   1324.75 \\
        {W2-J}  &   0.577232    &   1943    &   647.401 \\
        {W2-K}  &   0.591156    &   1960    &   684.953 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption[Best photometric colours from the MgII dataset]{Photometric colours with highest r-value from the MgII dataset.}
    \label{table:MgII_colours}

\end{table}
```

but it made this:

[image]

Why has it squashed up the middle two columns? I'm quite new to LaTex, and very new to `siunitx`.
Also, is there any way to avoid having to put the braces around the textual column entries? It's kind of a pain when there are a lot of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set appropriate values in your `table-format`s. In your case, you have to worry about the number of digits before and after the decimal separator and, in the second column, the presence of the sign.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0.3pt}
  \sisetup{group-digits=integer}
  \begin{tabular}{
    @{}
    l
    S[table-format=+1.6]
    S[table-format=5.0]
    S[table-format=4.3]
    @{}
    }
    \toprule
    Combo & {$|r|>0.5$} & {$n>100$} & {$r^2n$} \\
    \midrule
    U-V   & 0.558545    & 11640     & 3631.36  \\
    U-R   & 0.567270    & 11632     & 3743.12  \\
    U-I   & 0.579188    & 11626     & 3900.04  \\
    U-J   & 0.536106    & 3709      & 1066     \\
    U-K   & 0.535644    & 3730      & 1070.19  \\
    B-V   & 0.580019    & 11884     & 3998.04  \\
    B-R   & 0.574867    & 11763     & 3887.34  \\
    B-I   & 0.591288    & 11749     & 4107.7   \\
    V-U   & -0.558545   & 11640     & 3631.36  \\
    V-B   & -0.580019   & 11884     & 3998.04  \\
    R-U   & -0.567270   & 11632     & 3743.12  \\
    R-B   & -0.574867   & 11763     & 3887.34  \\
    R-W2  & -0.535443   & 4022      & 1153.1   \\
    I-U   & -0.579188   & 11626     & 3900.04  \\
    I-B   & -0.591288   & 11749     & 4107.7   \\
    I-W2  & -0.574056   & 4020      & 1324.75  \\
    J-U   & -0.536106   & 3709      & 1066     \\
    J-W2  & -0.577232   & 1943      & 647.401  \\
    K-U   & -0.535644   & 3730      & 1070.19  \\
    K-W1  & -0.512554   & 1938      & 509.136  \\
    K-W2  & -0.591156   & 1960      & 684.953  \\
    W1-K  & 0.512554    & 1938      & 509.136  \\
    W2-R  & 0.535443    & 4022      & 1153.1   \\
    W2-I  & 0.574056    & 4020      & 1324.75  \\
    W2-J  & 0.577232    & 1943      & 647.401  \\
    W2-K  & 0.591156    & 1960      & 684.953  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption[Best photometric colours from the MgII dataset]{Photometric colours with highest r-value from the MgII dataset.}
  \label{table:MgII_colours}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah that's better! Is there any way to avoid having to put the braces around the text values in the first column? Maybe a column format specifier or something?

Comment: @Jim421616 Your first column is an `l` type column, so as far as I know, you don't need the brace protection there already.

Comment: @Jim421616 I've added some small improvements (booktabs, in particular, but also better digit groupint).

Comment: Ok, so what does the line `\sisetup{group-digits=integer}` do exactly?

Comment: @Jim421616 It introduces grouping for larger numbers, but only for the integer part. `siunitx`'s default is to put a thin space between groups and to group by three digits, but doesn't separate a single digit (that is, you must have at least five numbers for the grouping to take place). Notice the five digit numbers in your third column, and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @Jim421616 Notice that, if you remove it, the grouping will still be there. Indeed, it is the default for both integer and decimal parts. What the option does is thus to restrict it only for the integer part. (You might like the default, though. Try and remove it, and check your decimal places in your second column).