# How do you pronounce \rightleftarrows?

Tags: arrows, pronunciation

I'm making a latex to speech library, and I have come across

```
\rightleftarrows
```

which looks like this:

```
⮂
```

which is in context to this equation:

```
\rm CO_2 + H_2O \rightleftarrows H_2CO_3 \rightleftarrows HCO_3^- + H^+
```

I tried looking for the symbol in Larry's speakeasy, which is a guide to verbalizing math, but that symbol was not in there.

Rather than simply saying, `Right Left Arrows.` , is there better terminology for this symbol?

Comment: That's the wrong arrow for the context: you want an equilibrium arrow, which is 'half' in each direction

Comment: Are you sure? Its from this Wikipedia Article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicarbonate_buffer_system (First Equation)

Comment: Yes: my 'day job' is as a chemistry lecturer!

Comment: @JosephWright Ha ha, okay well then I guess I need an answer for both.

Comment: On the arrows business, http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20127/what-is-the-difference-between-reaction-in-both-directions-and-equilibrium covers it (though it's _very_ rare to see `⇄`). On the main part of your question, I have a feeling it's off-topic as it's not really TeX related. For a chemistry context you'd read the equation as something like 'carbon dioxide plus water is in equilibrium with carbonate and protons'.

Comment: @JosephWright So should I say, `Reacts in both directions`?

Comment: chemically speaking, "reacts in both directions" is not entirely wrong, but the proper terminology is still "in equilibrium with"

Comment: Taking into account some of the comments on your previous related question I think you're going to end up needing a significant option on this library: What it's talking about, e.g. Chemistry/Physics/Maths  (you'll almost certainly need to subdivide at least some of these) as a particular symbol's meaning will differ (even if used properly e.g. `\rightarrow`, but more significantly they're not always used properly .  I suggest a "read the symbol name" variant as well (even if you decide not to implement field-specific meanings yet)

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah definitely. Luckily my use case does have some context. Fox example, Wikiarticles are supposed to have <math chem> tags </math> which could be useful. When I get around to cleaning up the source code and open sourcing it, hopefully we can add that.

Comment: Please use a dedicated chemistry package for typesetting chemical equations http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/typesetting-chemical-element-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equilibrium arrows you show for chemical equations usually look like this:
[image] which can be displayed using `\leftrightharpoons`

For your purposes of speech to text, while using "reacts in both directions" is not entirely wrong chemically speaking, the proper terminology is "in equilibrium with"