# How to use \s16o2 as a newcommand in latex and bibtex?

Tags: macros, bibtex

I would like to use the \s16o2 newcommand for S$^{16}$O$_2$. How to define it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: [Wellcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Have you seen this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/typesetting-chemical-element-names/145860#145860