# Non-italic text when using subscripts

Tags: equations, italic, italic-correction

I would like to use subscripts in text and display it non-italic. When using the `$_{}` the text is rendered italic. Can I change that behavior? 
How to achieve that (preferably as a default in TeXStudio).

Thanks!

Comment: Math variables are normally in italic, so perhaps you should be a bit more specific about what it is you are trying to do. It is true that textual subscripts should be not only upright but probably also in the text font not the math font, but that should not require setting the entire math in upright

Comment: Thanks @daleif. I wanted to write chemical equations, for example. They tend to have a lot of subscripts but are not expected to be italic. So maybe the actual question would be more precise: How to get subscripts in non-italic?

Comment: See [Typesetting chemical element names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145838/82917) and answers therein.

Comment: There are specialised packages for this, not need at all do to that by hand, see campas comment. But this information is very relevant to your question and your title, so you might want to update those.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use the package `mhchem` for chemical formulas, as mentioned in the question linked by @campa. But in general, if you are not writing chemical equations/formulas, you can use some solutions provided in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode.

Comment: Thanks @ Marijn. That was actually what I was looking for

Comment: A more general approach is to wrap the subscript in `\text{}` from `amsmath`.

Comment: With the new package [subtext](https://ctan.org/pkg/subtext), you can achieve your request with the syntax `x_[i]` instead of `x_{i}`.