# How not cross out headings of table after using the merge row command multiline?

Tags: tables, multirow, hline

Hi latex and texmaker experts

I am currently still new to latex and struggling to add horizontal lines to a table after using the multirow function in latex without crossing the headings of the table (It looks like text with a line straight through which is what I don't want).

Below is an example of my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\small
\caption{Refrigerant properties}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{Name}  & \multirow{2}{*}{Chemical Symbol} & \multirow{2}{*}{Boiling Point at atmospheric pressure C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Absolute Saturation Pressure $kPa$}\\ 
    \hline
    & & & $5C$ & $50C$\\ 
    \hline 
    $Refrigerant 717$ & $NH_{3}$ & $-33.4$ & $516$ & $2030$\\ 
    \hline 
    $Refrigerant 11$ & $CCL_{3}F$ & $+23.9$ & $49$ & $235$\\ 
    \hline 
    $Refrigerant 12$ & $CCl_{2}F_{2}$ & $-30$ & $362$ & $1200$\\ 
    \hline 

    \end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Below is an image of the crossed out headings after rows are merged
[image: Headings crossed out with horizontal line]

I would appreciate any help with the above.
Thanks Mat

Comment: Sorry about my typo in my heading. Meant to say - How not to cross out your headings in a table, after using the multirow (merge) command in textmaker. :)

Comment: Replace the second hline with cline{4-5}

Comment: Also, you might want to use a package dedicated to chemical formulae such as chemformula or mhch instead of using math mode.

Comment: Unrelated: the word `Refrigerant` should not be in math mode and the chemical formulas should be typeset upright: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/ I'd also take a look at the `siunitx` package…

Comment: Thanks for the tips. What package do I need for \cline?

Comment: Also, use \textit instead of math mode if you want italic text in the first column.

Comment: Really appreciate the useful answers and advice.

Comment: No special package for `\cline`: it is part of the latex kernel.

Comment: Thanks leandriis and Bernard. Worked beautiful. Keep safe and well. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose these improvements, using `siunitx` (for alignment on the decimal dot in numerical columns with the `S` column type, and a correct typetting of units), `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in standard cells, `caption`, for a correct spacing between caption and table, and one of the dedicated chemistry packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\captionsetup{skip = 4pt}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, table-format=5.0}
\caption{Refrigerant properties}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|S[table-format =-2.1]|*{2}{S|}}
    \hline
    \multirowcell{3}{Name} & \multirowcell{3}{Chemical\\ Symbol} & {\multirowcell{3}{Boiling Point at \\ atmospheric \\ pressure (\si{\celsius})}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makebox[0pt]{\makecell{Absolute\\ Saturation\\ Pressure (\si{\kPa})}}}\\
    \cline{4-5}
    & & & \SI{5}{\celsius} & \SI{50}{\celsius}\\
    \hline
    Refrigerant 717 & \ce{NH3} & -33.4 & 516 & 2030 \\
    \hline
    Refrigerant 11 & \ce{CCl3F} & +23.9 & 49 & 235 \\
    \hline
    Refrigerant 12 & \ce{CCl2F2} & -30 & 362 & 1200 \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

\[image]

Answer (score 1):

There a few things that can be improved about the table. First things first: the answer to you question is: use`\cline{4-5}` instead of `\hline` in the beginning of the second row.

I would like to propose to

- use a lot less lines, though, for the lines left use `booktabs` (package)
- maybe use `threeparttable` (package) to move some information,
- don't put the names in math mode
- use `siunitx` for the units and the columns which contain numbers
- use a package for chemical formulas (or one of the methods proposed here: [Typesetting Chemical Formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/)
- consider to let the table float (i.e., remove the `[H]` from the `table`)

All of this is up to you, of course, but just to give you an impression:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize}

\usepackage{chemformula,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Refrigerant properties}
    \begin{tabular}{llSSS}
      \toprule
        Name &
        Chemical Symbol &
        {$T_b$ in \si{\celsius}\tnote{a}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{$p$ in \si{\kilo\pascal}\tnote{b}} \\
        \cmidrule{4-5}
        & &  & {\SI{5}{\celsius}} & {\SI{50}{\celsius}} \\ 
      \midrule
        Refrigerant 717 & \ch{NH3}    & -33.4 & 516 & 2030 \\ 
        Refrigerant 11  & \ch{CCl3F}  & +23.9 & 49  & 235 \\ 
        Refrigerant 12  & \ch{CCl2F2} & -30   & 362 & 1200 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a] boiling point at atmospheric pressure
      \item[b] absolute saturation pressure
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]