# How to insert upright delta symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, chemistry

I need to insert upright delta symbol as [image]

But I did it as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\delta}^{18}\mathrm{O}$

\end{document}
```

[image] The delta symbol is not so upright?
So how should I get a upright delta symbol?

Comment: textgreek package provides `\textdelta`, then you can do it all in text mode; `\textdelta\textsuperscript{18}O`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your way is totally a new one to reslove the problem in text mode. So good! @Cicada

Comment: You can do direct input `δ ¹⁸O` if you can use fontspec package and have a suitable font (`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
δ ¹⁸O
\end{document}`) but better to use the chem packages.

Comment: Since discussion associated with the answers indicates that the question is about setting chemical notation, I have added a tag to that effect.  (It would have been useful to include this information in the original question.)

Comment: @Cicada Sorry for being late. I missed your last comment. How did you input the superscript in LaTeX plain file, such as δ ¹⁸O. It is magic.

Comment: ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰x₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₀: they are glyphs defined in Unicode. You will need a suitable font (e.g., Noto Serif), and a character map app if you want to inspect them. For ¹²³, U+00B9, U+00B3, U+00B2 ;for the rest, U+2070 etc.

Comment: @Cicada Thanks. The understanding of fonts should be before learning latex, otherwise, it is difficult to understand. That's my feeling now. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(I rewrote the answer to avoid creating any kind of impression that I might somehow be claiming that one LaTeX chemistry package might be "better" than another. For a broad examination of the pros and cons of various LaTeX chemistry packages, please check out the posting [Typesetting Chemical Formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145838/5001).)

First, assuming that the "raised-18-upright-capital-O" denotes a particular isotope of oxygen, I strongly recommend you employ the macros of a LaTeX chemistry package to typeset chemical formulas and equations. For instance, you could load the `mhchem` package and employ its `\ce` macro.

Second, for the upright-delta symbol, how to proceed depends on which text and math font families you employ:

- If your document employs the default fonts (Computer Modern), you could load the `upgreek` package and employ that package's `\updelta` macro instead of `\delta`.
- If you wish to use Times Roman fonts for your document -- I raise this point because the glyphs shown in the OP's screenshots look like they could be from the Times Roman family -- you could do so by loading the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. Happily, the `\newtxmath` also provides a macro called `\updelta` that you could use for your chemical formula.
- According to the user guide of the `mhchem` package, other packages (besides `upgreek` and `\newtxmath`) that provide access to a macro called `\updelta` are `textgreek`, `kpfonts`, `mathdesign`, `fourier`, `textalpha`, `newpxmath`, and `unicode-math`.
- Interestingly, if one of these font packages is loaded, the `\ce` macro will *automatically* use the upright greek letter -- here, `\updelta` -- while evaluating the expression `\ce{\delta^18O}`.

[image]

I suppose that the slight gap after the upright lowercase-delta symbol  helps clarify that we're not dealing "delta raised to the 18th power".

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman fonts (text and math)
\usepackage{mhchem} % for \ce macro

\begin{document}
$\delta$ vs.\ $\updelta$

$\updelta\ce{^18O}$

\ce{\delta^18O} % note use of "\delta" _inside_ "\ce"
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you feel there is too much blank between `\updelta` and `\ce{^18O}`?

Comment: @Y.zeng - Not really. The slight gap helps to make clear to the reader that we're not talking about `\updelta` to the 18-th power. Of course, this assumes that you're really trying to typeset something related to an isotope of oxygen. Only you know if that's the case. Please let me know if what you're trying to typeset is, in fact, the 18th power of `\updelta`.

Comment: I am going to talk about `an isotope of oxygen`, so is it better to use `\ce{^{18}O}`?

Comment: @Y.zeng - `$\ce{^{18}O}$` is very helpful because it incorporates the *meaning* of what you're writing about. (The `\ce` macro works in both text and math mode.) In contrast, `${}^{18}\mathrm{O}` does not convey any meaning, does it?

Comment: Okay, I will use this one `$\updelta\ce{^18O}$`

Comment: I’ll note that if you use `chemmacros` rather than `mhchem`, you get the upright letters ‘for free’, even in textmode: `\chemdelta\ch{^{18}O}`.

Comment: @bradrn I see that most people use `mhchem`, but only a few people use `chemmacros`. What's the reason? Is `chemmacros` not as useful as `mhchem`?

Comment: @Y.zeng I disagree: as far as I’m aware, `chemmacros` is more popular than `mhchem`, or at the very least they’re equally popular. In any case, `chemmacros` has a lot of useful features which are missing from `mhchem`.

Comment: @Y.zeng - Both `mhchem` and `chemmacros` are fine LaTeX packages with a lot of happy users. What is the basis for your claim that "most people use `mhchem`, but only [a] few people use `chemmacros`? A search of the keywords `mhchem` and `chemmacros` on this site yields 1701 and 663 "hits", respecitively. While these simple numbers might (but probably should not!) be interpreted as "`mhchem` is more widely used than `chemmacros` in general", they should absolutely not be interpreted as "`chemmacros` is not as useful as `mhchem`".

Comment: @bradrn - I've revised my answer thoroughly so as to avoid creating an impression that I was somehow favoring the `mhchem` package over others.

Comment: @bradrn You are right. I will use ‘chemmacros` in the future.

Comment: @Mico I will use ’chemmacros` in the future. I find it has more features.

Comment: @bradrn Why can't I use `mhchem` and `chemmacros` simultaneously?

Comment: @Y.zeng - Your latest follow-up query is completely orthogonal to your original question. TeX.SE is *not* some kind of general chat or discussion board. If you want to dig deeper into *why* `mhchem` and `chemmacros` are not full compatible with each other, *please ask a new query*. Do be aware, though, that why-type questions are unlikely to generate answers that many people would find interesting. (E.g., the most plausible answer to your "why" question obviously is, "because the packages were written by different sets of people for whom interoperability was not a goal".)

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your reminder. I just can't run these codes: `$\updelta\ce{^18O}$\chemdelta\ch{^{18}O}`. It seems I can't load `mhchem` and `chemmacros` packages in one file.

Comment: @Y.zeng - Indeed, the packages are not fully interoperable, and that is why you cannot run `\ce{^18O}$\chemdelta\ch{^{18}O}`. You're aware of this issue, as otherwise you wouldn't have asked earlier as to *why* the packages aren't fully interoperable. While that's an issue that may be relevant for some people, it is utterly unrelated to your original query, which was about how to typeset a term that happens to involve a chemical item (as well as a certain greek letter). And that is why I've asked you to post a *new* query instead of treating TeX.SE as some kind of generic discussion board.

Comment: @Mico I know your idea now. I am not aware of something of the Latex core.

Comment: @bradrn `\chemdelta\ce{^{18}O}` also works “out of the box” with only loading `mhchem` (as both `chemmacros` and `mhchem` load `chemgreek` behind the scene). However, without specifying how upright Greek letters should be printed `\chemdelta` gives an *italic* delta.

Comment: @Y.zeng on the contrary `chemmacros` is *fully* compatible with `mhchem`. The `\ch` command is *not* (!) defined by `chemmacros`. If you load both `chemmacros` and `mhchem` you will get an undefined control sequence error. You are probably mistaking `chemmacros` for `chemformula` (which is the package that defines `\ch` and is loaded by `chemmacros` if users don't also load `mhchem` or tell `chemmacros` to do so.)

Comment: @cgnieder When I loaded `chemmacros`, `mhchem` and `chemformula`, I can run `$\ce{^18O}$\chemdelta\ch{^{18}O}` successfully, but the delta symbol is *itlic*. What's the reason?

Comment: @Y.zeng you should choose either `mhchem` *or* `chemformula` and stick with one. Using both only leads to inconsistent layout.

Comment: @Y.zeng The `chemgreek` (loaded by both `chemmacros` and `mhchem`) package defines `\chemdelta`. But you need it to help it with the choice which Greek letters to use. This is explained in the `chemmacros` manual section 11 (and in the `chemgreek` manual). `chemmacros` probably writes in your log: “*You haven't loaded any package for upright  letters or no unique choice was possible. Either load one of packages specified in the manual or select a chemgreek mapping manually.*”

Comment: @cgnieder Okay. Thanks for your explanation. I check that.

Answer (score 2):

Use package `upgreek`, and then use `\updelta`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
$\updelta^{18} \mathrm{O}$
\end{document}
```

This should give you the following:

[image]

Comment: Assuming that 18-before-O denotes an isotope of oxygen, you should do yourself a big favor and (a) load the `mhchem` package and (b) write either `\ce{^18O}` or, slightly easier to parse, `\ce{^{18}O}`.

Comment: @Mico If I do as you said, the blank between `\delta` and `\ce{^18O}` is too big. The code is `$\updelta\ce{^18O}$`

Comment: @Y.zeng - If the expression really is about a particular isotope of oxygen, there *should* be a slight gap between `\updelta` and `\ce{^{18}O}`. In the screenshot I posted with my answer, there is such a gap, which helps to make clear that we're not talking about the 18-th power of `\updelta` but, rather, `\updelta` followed by an expression for a particular isotope of oxygen.

Comment: @Mico I see they are the same with gap and without the gap.

Comment: @Y.zeng - Sorry, I don't understand your latest comment. Which things are "the same"?

Comment: `\ce{^{18}O}` and `\ce{^18O}` have the same output. @Mico

Comment: @Y.zeng - Thanks for this clarification. Yes, the *outputs* of `\ce{^{18}O}` and `\ce{^18O}` are indeed exactly the same. What I *meant to* express earlier was that `\ce{^{18}O}` may be easier to parse and debut in the *input*. Sorry for not expressing this thought sufficiently clearly.

Comment: @Mico I know now. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

The `unicode-math` package provides both `\updelta`,`\mupdelta`, and `\symup{\delta}`. It requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  I recommend that you use this if you can and legacy 8-bit math fonts if you have to.

If you have to, many other packages provide either `\updelta` or `\deltaup`.

There are only two 8-bit TeX encodings with upright Greek lowercase letters: OML (which contains Latin and Greek math symbols) and LGR (which covers polytonic Greek).  You can load an OML-encoded upright font with `isomath` and then use `\mathrm{\delta}` as you thought.. The Math Design fonts are some of the only 8-bit math fonts that support upright lowercase Greek.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[rmdefault=mdput, OMLmathrm]{isomath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\mathrm{\delta}^{18}\mathrm{O} \\
  &\delta^{18}\mathrm{O}
\end{align*}
```

[image: Math Design Utopia sample]

The above uses `mdput`, or Math Design Utopia, which is also compatible with `fourier`.  The available options (Math Design Garamond, Utopia or Charter) are [documented  in section 4.2.2 of the `isomath` manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.html)

If you want to use an 8-bit font other than these, you would declare it as a symbol alphabet.  Since Euler uses the same mapping for its Greek and Latin letters as the standard OML, but is technically declared as a `U` encoding, the above will not work for Euler, but the following will:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathrm}{bold}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\mathrm{\delta}^{18}\mathrm{O} \\
  &\delta^{18}\mathrm{O}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Palatino + AMS Euler sample]

A few notes: Hermann Zapf originally designed AMS Euler to complement the font Concrete (for DEK’s book, *Concrete Mathematics*), but he also designed Palatino and Optima, which also make excellent complements to it.  You also might prefer to use a different alphabet for upright math symbols, perhaps calling it `\symup`, and leave `\mathrm` unchanged for text such as `if`.

If your 8-bit font has its upright Greek letters in different slots, you should first look for a package that defines symbols such as `\updelta`, such as `upgreek`.  Most Greek text fonts do not have them, however.  This minimal example shows how to do it with a LGR-encoded font (Tempora, complementing Times, but for practical real-world use, you would probably want `newtxmath` for this).

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\DeclareSymbolFont{elup}{LGR}{Tempora-TLF}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{elup}{bold}{LGR}{Tempora-TLF}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\updelta}{\mathalpha}{elup}{"64}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\updelta^{18}\mathrm{O} \\
  &\delta^{18}\mathrm{O}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Times + Tempora sample]

This also works for Computer Modern:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{elup}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{elup}{bold}{LGR}{cmr}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\updelta}{\mathalpha}{elup}{"64}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\updelta^{18}\mathrm{O} \\
  &\delta^{18}\mathrm{O}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

The layouts of LGR and OML are documented [in “LaTeX Font Encodings,”](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf) or else a specific package might document its own custom encoding.

Finally, you can use any LGR-encoded Greek text font in math mode (such as the ones from the Greek Font Society) with the `mathastext` package.

Comment: I am very curious why you know so much! I want to good at Latex as you!

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Want it? Write it. Compile with xelatex or lualatex and use a suitable font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\def\su#1{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\begin{document}
 δ\su{81} O
```

%want italic? alright!

```
{\it δ} \su{81} O
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but only in text mode with no unusual formatting. For many chemistry papers, the OP probably needs math mode. It would also come out as italicized or small caps if the surrounding text is. But `\textnormal{δ}` would work in both modes.