# List comma-separated chemical formula within the sentence

Tags: punctuation, chemistry, mhchem

NiCl2, NaPO_2H2, C4H4Na2O4, and HF. I have to list these chemicals within a sentence. But when I tried to put superscript and subscript, the remaining sentence and the whole paragraph are changing into italics. How to solve this?
\begin{commalist} is not working as well

Comment: You've stumbled on the first issue listed in [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33472/5764).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Since you've set the `mhchem` tag: Why aren't you writing `\ce{NiCl2}, \ce{NaPO2H2}, \ce{C4H4Na2O4}, and \ce{HF}.`?

Comment: You should be using one of the solutions in [best practices - Typesetting Chemical Formulas - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/typesetting-chemical-formulas)  anyway. As a side effect that will solve your issue.