# Sub-/Superscripts in Headings/Normal Text

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, subscripts, superscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to typeset subscript in usual text mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode)

I sometimes want to typeset something simple like `$N_2$` or `$3^2$` in a Heading, other times in a paragraph of normal text.
I want all of it to be typeset in the surrounding font.
In normal text this works quite good with `$\textrm{N}^\textrm{2}$`, even though it is too complicated.
For Headings I have to know how my headings are typeset (if they use sans, italic, bold, etc.)
And if I then use the appropriate command and later change my mind about heading formatting, I have to redo it.
Is there a command to somehow "step out" of math into whatever is the highermost level of current formatting?

So far I could only find answers like: use this package, or this command (that only solves a specialized case).
I am looking for a more general understanding of what's going on, does someone have a link at hand to a short summary to the fonts and their interaction in LaTeX?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1013/16895

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type your superscripts and subscripts using `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript` respectively. The former is defined in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) while the latter could be defined similarly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% \textsubscript defined equivalent to \textsuperscript in latex.ltx
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsubscript[1]{%
  \@textsubscript{\selectfont#1}}
\def\@textsubscript#1{%
  {\m@th\ensuremath{_{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section $N^2$ and $N_2$}
\section{Section N\textsuperscript{2} and N\textsubscript{2}}
\end{document}
```

[`fixltx2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) also provides the above defintion by default. So, adding

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e
```

to your document preamble would allow you to use `\textsubscript`.

Comment: `fixltx2e` defines `\textsubscript`: I'd always load this package for the fix to `\(` ... `\)` anyway.

Comment: This answer, or at least the `fixltx2e` portion of it, is now depreciated. All fixes from the package were migrated into the latex kernel in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the complicated phrases, which I often encounter when I want multi-character subscripts, I would normally put macros like these at the start of the document.

```
%Macros    
% Italic text with italic exponent
\newcommand{\me}[2]{\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}^\mathit{#2}}}
% Normal text with normal exponent
\newcommand{\te}[2]{\ensuremath{\textrm{#1}^\textrm{#2}}} 
% Italic text with italic multi-character subscript index
\newcommand{\ms}[2]{\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}_\mathit{#2}}}
% Normal text with normal subscript index
\newcommand{\ts}[2]{\ensuremath{\textrm{#1}_\textrm{#2}}}
```

They can be used inside or outside of the math environments.