# \raisebox command for subscript

Tags: macros, subscripts

I was wondering if anyone know make a command for raisebox subscript? [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode) asks how to make the subscript part...here I want to make the command shorter by having a macro do the work rather than having to type out the whole command each time.

```
some\raisebox{-.4ex}{\scriptsize thing}
```

comes out as

> some<sub>thing</sub>

I thought something like

```
\newcommand{\mysubscript}[1]{\raisebox{-.4ex}{\scriptsize #1}}
```

would work, but unfortunately it only prints the first letter of the argument

```
some\mysubscript[thing]{}
```

> some<sub>t</sub>hing

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you say `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`, you have available `\textsubscript`: `some\textsubscript{thing}`

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to typeset subscript in usual text mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1013/5764)

Comment: Your use of `\mysubscript` is incorrect. Try `some\mysubscript{thing}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can also be done with the `stackengine` package as follows.  The optional argument specifies the depth below baseline you want to move the subscript.  I default it to .5ex.   Note that the "L" `\stacktype` denotes the stack as "long" wherein the length specified is the distance from the original baseline to the understacked baseline.  If the `\stacktype` were denoted as "S" (short), the length would denote the gap from the original baseline to the top of the understacked object.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\tss[2][.5ex]{%
  \def\stacktype{L}%
  \belowbaseline[#1]{\scriptsize#2}%
}
\begin{document}
some\tss{thing} and some\tss[1ex]{thing} else
\end{document}
```

[image]