# How to get small numbers (For example q0)

Tags: sharelatex

I'm still new to Latex, and I can't seem how to write f.ex. q0 where the 0 is small. Hard to explain/search google when I don't know what you call this in english.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Do you mean a subscript? Try: $q_0$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is subscript and you write it like this: `$q_0$`.

Note that this only works in math mode. The `$` tell LaTeX to switch from text to math mode or back (there are different possibilities of switching to math mode, see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments)).

When you want to have multiple digits (or other symbols) in subscript, you will have to enclose them in curly braces (`q_{12 + x}`), since the `_` only "sees" the next symbol. The curly braces make LaTeX see everything inside as a group that cannot be separated.

If you want to use subscript in normal text, have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode).

Superscript works the same way but with `^` instead of `_`. Write `x^2` for x².

Comment: I'd like to add that adding dollar signs around the expression will avoid a horrible spam of errors. (So it's important to let LaTeX know that you're using math code)

Comment: Unless you mean `oldstyle` (lowercase) numbers.  You can have them with `\oldstylenums{25}` for instance.

Comment: One more question, what if it is supposed to be "up"? Like 2^2 = 4?

Comment: @user16655 You just write exactly that, except between the dollar signs, $2^2=4$. If you want to have multiple characters in the sub- or super-script, you have to enclose them in curly braces - $2^{12}=4096$, $q_{0,1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer :) I really appreciate it. It's a lot of symbols to learn ;)

Comment: @user16655: I added some more detail to the answer. If you are very new to LaTeX, consider having a look at an introduction, like [this one](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf), first. It's even available in [many different languages](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort).