# How to use fixltx2e only when necessary

Tags: versions, fixltx2e

I've been using the [fixltx2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) package for a while, with a tweak described [here on the site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204529/5640). Recently, this has gotten me the following error message:

> ```
> Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
> (fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
> (fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.
> ```

How do I *robustly* make sure `fixltx2e` is used exactly when necessary?

Comment: Just ignore the warning, if you plan to use the same document with pre 2015 kernels. Otherwise remove `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`.

Comment: Since it's just a warning, you can [silence it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25047/5764): `\usepackage{silence} \WarningFilter{fixltx2e}{}`.

Comment: @Werner If you're already turning off all the warnings for a given package non-selectively, you might as well use the command designed to do just that: `\WarningsOff[fixltx2e]`. Note that either way, this command needs to be placed BEFORE you load the `fixltx2e` package (using `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` or `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}`) for it to work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can distinguish pre-2015 kernels from the fact that `\IncludeInRelease` is not defined:

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname IncludeInRelease\endcsname\relax
  \usepackage{fixltx2e}
\fi
```

See [What does \begingroup\expandafter…\endgroup do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24393/what-does-begingroup-expandafter-endgroup-do) for an explanation of the code.

Comment: Why aren't lines 2-4 in your snippet sufficient? You kind of lost me with the first line.

Comment: @einpoklum Omitting the first line would leave `\IncludeInRelease` defined to be equivalent to `\relax`, if previously undefined. With the first line, the `\csname` construction is performed when the group has not yet been closed. When `\endgroup` performs its actions (which include removing the previous setting of `\IncludeInRelease`, if done). See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24393/what-does-begingroup-expandafter-endgroup-do

Comment: Also, why not use something like `\ifcsname`?

Comment: @einpoklum If your aim is to make the code compatible with older releases of TeX, you can't assume e-TeX.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `TeXLive` you can use the solution below to obtain which version you are running.

### References:

- [Automatically Determine which TeXLive Version is being used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96570/automatically-determine-which-texlive-version-is-being-used/)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter%
\def\getversion{\expandafter\get@version\pdftexbanner\@nil}%
\def\get@version#1201#2)#3\@nil{\def\TeXLiveVersion{201#2}}%
\makeatother%
\getversion%

\ifnum\TeXLiveVersion<2015\relax%
    \usepackage{fixltx2e}%
    \typeout{*** Included fixltx2e}
\elese
    \typeout{*** DId NOT Included fixltx2e}
\fi%


\begin{document}
xxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: er why not just use `\fmtversion` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, did not know about `\fmtversion`.

Comment: `\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2015/01/01}{yes}{no}` :-)

Comment: Ah, but I can't assume I use TeXLive, now can I...?