# What packages are no longer necessary after TeX Live 2015 kernel update?

Tags: updating, latex-base, obsolete

I see from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287146/how-to-use-fixltx2e-only-when-necessary) that [`fixltx2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e) is no longer needed. This means the LaTeX kernel now finally has a `\textsubscript` command. Formerly that was provided by `fixltx2e` and also by the `subscript` package, which is now also obsolete.

Are any other packages rendered obsolete by the update to the kernel in 2015?

Comment: etex.sty and luatexbase (mostly)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`fixltx2e`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e), [`etex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etex), [`morefloats`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/morefloats), [`latexrelease`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexrelease) are all affected to some extent.

At each LaTeX release there is a one or two page newsletter describing the main changes (ltnews 22 and 23 for the 2015/01/01 and 2015/10/01 releases, respectively) these days we bundle them as one file `texdoc ltnews` or `ltnews.pdf` from CTAN.

As detailed in ltnews 23 `fixltx2e` is obsolete, all the fixes that were in that package have now been applied to the format and instead a new package, `latexrelease`, allows you to back them out if needed.

Also in the January release, LaTeX started using extended register allocations by default and introduced a new `\extrafloats` command to access more float boxes (for figures and tables, etc.) so `etex.sty` shouldn't normally be used and the contributed `morefloats` package isn't really needed (although it's been updated to use `\extrafloats` internally if defined so using it does no harm).

As noted in ltnews 23, the October release incorporated a lot of support for LuaTeX, mostly a refactoring of the existing contributed [`luatexbase`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luatexbase) code so `luatexbase` should not normally be used. (`luatexbase` as distributed is now a stub that defines a thin compatibility layer for some of the older commands that were not exactly copied, but otherwise uses the new code.)

So of these only really `etex.sty` shouldn't be used. If it is used, then in order to get maximum compatibility it overwrites the new register allocation mechanism with its original one, so losing many of the new features.

`fixltx2e` is harmless if used, it does nothing and just gives a warning message.

`morefloats` is fine, it uses the new mechanisms internally if used on a new engine, it's just that the problems it solved are less likely to occur now, and the `\extrafloats` syntax can be used.

`luatexbase` is also fine, it adds a compatibility layer emulating the older package of the same name but does not affect code written to the new LaTeX base LuaTeX support.