# Error with \textsubscript

Tags: packages, subscripts, updating

I am seeing this in the body of the latex format for a journal I want to publish with. But it's prompting an error.

What does this mean `CO\textsubscript` and which package do I have to include to be able to use it?

Comment: `\textsubscript` is available in directly in LaTeX, but i takes an argument, such as `x\textsubscript{b}`

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please some working code.

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This command was not part of LaTeX until 2015, so if you (or your publisher) are using an older version the command may not be defined by default.

In that case you need the `subscript` package: `\usepackage{subscript}`.

Another more comprehensive solution for pre-2015 distribution is the `fixltx2e` package (the elements of which are now incorporated into LaTeX itself).

Once the command is defined (by either package, or by an updated LaTeX core), you write `CO\textsubscript{2}` for carbon dioxide.

Comment: how old had be `latex` that `\subscript{...}` is not defined?

Comment: @Zarko https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150014/56233